# How to run a command with a timeout so that it is killed if it exceeds the timeout threshold?

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543#637753) to [Command line command to auto-kill a command after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543)

proposes a 1-line method to timeout a long-running command from the bash command line:

```
( /path/to/slow command with options ) & sleep 5 ; kill $!
```

But it's possible that a given "long-running" command may finish earlier than the timeout.
(Let's call it a "typically-long-running-but-sometimes-fast" command, or *tlrbsf* for fun.)

So this nifty 1-liner approach has a couple of problems.
First, the `sleep` isn't conditional, so that sets an undesirable lower bound on the time taken for the sequence to finish. Consider 30s or 2m or even 5m for the sleep, when the *tlrbsf* command finishes in 2 seconds — highly undesirable.
Second, the `kill` is unconditional, so this sequence will attempt to kill a non-running process and whine about it.

So...

**Is there a way** to timeout a typically-long-running-but-sometimes-fast (*"tlrbsf"*) command that

- has a bash implementation (the other question already has Perl and C answers)
- will terminate at the earlier of the two: *tlrbsf* program termination, or timeout elapsed
- will not kill non-existing/non-running processes (or, optionally: will not *complain* about a bad kill)
- doesn't have to be a 1-liner
- can run under Cygwin or Linux

... and, for bonus points

- runs the *tlrbsf* command in the foreground
- any 'sleep' or extra process in the background

such that the stdin/stdout/stderr of the *tlrbsf* command can be redirected, same as if it had been run directly?

If so, please share your code. If not, please explain why.

I have spent awhile trying to hack the aforementioned example but I'm hitting the limit of my bash skills.

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782/how-do-i-limit-the-running-time-of-a-bash-script (but I think the 'timeout3' answer here is much better).

Comment: Any reason to not use the gnu `timeout` utility?

Comment: `timeout` is great! you can even use with **multiple commands** (multi-line script): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888916/658497

Answer (score 171, accepted):

I think this is precisely what you are asking for:

http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# The Bash shell script executes a command with a time-out.
# Upon time-out expiration SIGTERM (15) is sent to the process. If the signal
# is blocked, then the subsequent SIGKILL (9) terminates it.
#
# Based on the Bash documentation example.

# Hello Chet,
# please find attached a "little easier"  :-)  to comprehend
# time-out example.  If you find it suitable, feel free to include
# anywhere: the very same logic as in the original examples/scripts, a
# little more transparent implementation to my taste.
#
# Dmitry V Golovashkin <Dmitry.Golovashkin@sas.com>

scriptName="${0##*/}"

declare -i DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=9
declare -i DEFAULT_INTERVAL=1
declare -i DEFAULT_DELAY=1

# Timeout.
declare -i timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
# Interval between checks if the process is still alive.
declare -i interval=DEFAULT_INTERVAL
# Delay between posting the SIGTERM signal and destroying the process by SIGKILL.
declare -i delay=DEFAULT_DELAY

function printUsage() {
    cat <<EOF

Synopsis
    $scriptName [-t timeout] [-i interval] [-d delay] command
    Execute a command with a time-out.
    Upon time-out expiration SIGTERM (15) is sent to the process. If SIGTERM
    signal is blocked, then the subsequent SIGKILL (9) terminates it.

    -t timeout
        Number of seconds to wait for command completion.
        Default value: $DEFAULT_TIMEOUT seconds.

    -i interval
        Interval between checks if the process is still alive.
        Positive integer, default value: $DEFAULT_INTERVAL seconds.

    -d delay
        Delay between posting the SIGTERM signal and destroying the
        process by SIGKILL. Default value: $DEFAULT_DELAY seconds.

As of today, Bash does not support floating point arithmetic (sleep does),
therefore all delay/time values must be integers.
EOF
}

# Options.
while getopts ":t:i:d:" option; do
    case "$option" in
        t) timeout=$OPTARG ;;
        i) interval=$OPTARG ;;
        d) delay=$OPTARG ;;
        *) printUsage; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# $# should be at least 1 (the command to execute), however it may be strictly
# greater than 1 if the command itself has options.
if (($# == 0 || interval <= 0)); then
    printUsage
    exit 1
fi

# kill -0 pid   Exit code indicates if a signal may be sent to $pid process.
(
    ((t = timeout))

    while ((t > 0)); do
        sleep $interval
        kill -0 $$ || exit 0
        ((t -= interval))
    done

    # Be nice, post SIGTERM first.
    # The 'exit 0' below will be executed if any preceeding command fails.
    kill -s SIGTERM $$ && kill -0 $$ || exit 0
    sleep $delay
    kill -s SIGKILL $$
) 2> /dev/null &

exec "$@"
```

Comment: That's a keen trick, using $$ for the background part. And nice that it will kill a hung tlrbsf immediately. But ugh, you have to choose a polling interval. And if you set the polling too low, it will eat CPU with constant signaling, making the tlrbsf run even longer!

Comment: You don't have to choose the polling interval, it has a default of 1s, that is pretty good. And the checking is very inexpensive, the overhead is negligible. I doubt that would make tlrbsf run noticeably longer. I tested with sleep 30, and got 0.000ms difference between using and not using it.

Comment: Right, I see that now. And it meets my exact requirements if you set the poll interval == timeout. Also works in pipelines, works with the whole thing backgrounded, works with multiple instances and other jobs running. Sweet, thanks!

Comment: Sending a signal kills the sub-shell, so I thought that lining all kill commands on one line will preserve them.  I also enabled stderr output to display unexpected errors.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay/14147112#14147112

Comment: @Juliano That's a great way to handle timeouts, very useful. I wonder if there is a way in which we can have the script return exitcode 143 when the process is killed after timeout? I tried adding "exit 143" right after the kill command, but I always get exit code 0 at the caller script.

Comment: Is the '''exec''' at the end required? I would like to use this code as a function, and exec will of course not work in a function because after executing the command, exec does not return.

Comment: Yes, `exec` is required since what this script does is set it up for its own "suicide" using `$$` a few times to get is PID, then it replaces itself with the process to be monitored (preserving its PID).

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't handle being passed the command `:` well.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting `Terminate` feedback. For code:
`bash timeout.sh -t 0 gcc helloworld.c |& tee output.txt`
I get a console string, but somehow `Terminate` is not piped into output.txt, but I want it to be there as well.

Answer (score 689):

You are probably looking for the `timeout` command in coreutils. Since it's a part of coreutils, it is technically a C solution, but it's still coreutils. `info timeout` for more details.
Here's an example:

```
timeout 5 /path/to/slow/command with options
```

Comment: In Mac you can install this via Macports or homebrew.

Comment: This, combined with [`run-one`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/run-one/), and [`curl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email) for reporting.

Comment: When installed via homebrew on OS X the command becomes ```gtimeout```

Comment: doesn't exist in coreutils-4.5.3

Comment: ... what OS are you using that has coreutils from before 2003?

Comment: @Keith: CentOS 5.10, for example :-(

Comment: @ethicalhack3r Right, most GNU commands go from `command` to `gcommand` on non-Linux OSes.

Comment: Is there a return value? like if timeout it returns 1 else 0

Comment: @Zero `timeout` exits 124 on timeout.

Comment: `timeout` wart: on some Linux (e.g. Cents 6.7), `timeout` responds as expected to SIGINT and SIGQUIT _unless_ you run it inside a bash script. Inside a bash script, `timeout` somehow ignores both.

Comment: To clarify, the homebrew command you need on OSX/mac is `brew install coreutils`, and then you can use `gtimeout`.

Comment: 5 here is for 5 seconds (default). 
for 5 minutes, command will be : `timeout 5m /path/to/slow/command with options`
for 5 hours, command will be `timeout 5h /path/to/slow/command with options`

Comment: @garth-kidd try running timeout with --foreground when running inside script.

Comment: I installed with `brew install coreutils` and then had `timeout` available immediately from shell.

Comment: Can we can another command after the time out using `&&`?/

Comment: I love simple answers. This should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 49):

This solution works regardless of bash monitor mode. You can use the proper signal to terminate your_command

```
#!/bin/sh
( your_command ) & pid=$!
( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
```

The watcher kills your_command after given timeout; the script waits for the slow task and terminates the watcher. Note that `wait` does not work with processes which are children of a different shell.

### Examples:

- your_command runs more than 2 seconds and was terminated

> your_command interrupted

```
( sleep 20 ) & pid=$!
( sleep 2 && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
if wait $pid 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "your_command finished"
    pkill -HUP -P $watcher
    wait $watcher
else
    echo "your_command interrupted"
fi
```

- your_command finished before the timeout (20 seconds)

> your_command finished

```
( sleep 2 ) & pid=$!
( sleep 20 && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
if wait $pid 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "your_command finished"
    pkill -HUP -P $watcher
    wait $watcher
else
    echo "your_command interrupted"
fi
```

Comment: `wait` returns the exit status of the process that it waits on. So if your command does exit within the allotted time but with a non-zero exit status then the logic here will behave as it it timed out, i.e. print `your_command interrupted`. Instead you _could_ do the `wait` without an `if` and then check if the `$watcher` pid still exists, if it does then you know you didn't timeout.

Comment: I can't figure out why this uses `kill` in one case but `pkill` in the other.  I needed to use `pkill` for both to make this work correctly.  I would expect that if you wrap a command in `()`, then you will need to use `pkill` to kill it.  But perhaps it works differently if there is only a single command inside the `()`.

Comment: God bless you sir :)

Answer (score 38):

To timeout the `slowcommand` after 1 second:

`timeout 1 slowcommand || echo "I failed, perhaps due to time out"`

To determine whether the command timed out or failed for its own reasons, check whether the status code is 124:

```
# ping the address 8.8.8.8 for 3 seconds, but timeout after only 1 second
timeout 1 ping 8.8.8.8 -w3
EXIT_STATUS=$?
if [ $EXIT_STATUS -eq 124 ]
then
echo 'Process Timed Out!'
else
echo 'Process did not timeout. Something else went wrong.'
fi
exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

Note that when the exit status is 124, you don't know whether it timed out due to your `timeout` command, or whether the command itself terminated due to some internal timeout logic of its own and then returned 124. You can safely assume in either case, though, that a timeout of some kind happened.

Answer (score 29):

There you go:

```
timeout --signal=SIGINT 10 /path/to/slow command with options
```

you may change the `SIGINT` and `10` as you desire ;)

Comment: "timeout" is part of **coreutils** package on (at least) Redhat, Centos, Suse and Ubuntu, so you'll need to install that if you don't have it.

Comment: it's really helpful!!!!!! Do you know why yingted's "timeout 5 /path/to/slow/command with options" sometimes not working?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not in the `coreutils` package on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this entirely with `bash 4.3` and above:

```
_timeout() { ( set +b; sleep "$1" & "${@:2}" & wait -n; r=$?; kill -9 `jobs -p`; exit $r; ) }
```

- Example: `_timeout 5 longrunning_command args`
- Example: `{ _timeout 5 producer || echo KABOOM $?; } | consumer`
- Example: `producer | { _timeout 5 consumer1; consumer2; }`
- Example: `{ while date; do sleep .3; done; } | _timeout 5 cat | less`
- Needs Bash 4.3 for `wait -n`
- Gives 137 if the command was killed, else the return value of the command.
- Works for pipes.  (You do not need to go foreground here!)
- Works with internal shell commands or functions, too.
- Runs in a subshell, so no variable export into the current shell, sorry.

If you do not need the return code, this can be made even simpler:

```
_timeout() { ( set +b; sleep "$1" & "${@:2}" & wait -n; kill -9 `jobs -p`; ) }
```

Notes:

- Strictly speaking you do not need the `;` in `; )`, however it makes thing more consistent to the `; }`-case.  And the `set +b` probably can be left away, too, but better safe than sorry.
- Except for `--forground` (probably) you can implement all variants `timeout` supports.  `--preserve-status` is a bit difficult, though.  This is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

This recipe can be used "naturally" in the shell (as natural as for `flock fd`):

```
(
set +b
sleep 20 &
{
YOUR SHELL CODE HERE
} &
wait -n
kill `jobs -p`
)
```

However, as explained above, you cannot re-export environment variables into the enclosing shell this way naturally.

Edit:

Real world example: Time out `__git_ps1` in case it takes too long (for things like slow SSHFS-Links):

```
eval "__orig$(declare -f __git_ps1)" && __git_ps1() { ( git() { _timeout 0.3 /usr/bin/git "$@"; }; _timeout 0.3 __orig__git_ps1 "$@"; ) }
```

Edit2: Bugfix.  I noticed that `exit 137` is not needed and makes `_timeout` unreliable at the same time.

Edit3: `git` is a die-hard, so it needs a double-trick to work satisfyingly.

Edit4: Forgot a `_` in the first `_timeout` for the real world GIT example.

---

Update 2023-08-06:  I found a better way to restrict the runtime of `git`, so the above is just an example.

> The following is no more bash-only as it needs `setsid`.  But I found no way to *reliably* create process group leaders with just `bash` idioms, sorry.
>
> This recipe is a bit more difficult to use, but very effective, as it not only kills the child, it also kills everything the child places in the same process group.

[I now use following](https://gist.github.com/hilbix/2bd39b26280ad7d99712):

```
__git_ps1() { setsid -w /bin/bash -c 'sleep 1 & . /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt && __git_ps1 "$@" & wait -n; p=$(/usr/bin/ps --no-headers -opgrp $$) && [ $$ = ${p:-x} ] && /usr/bin/kill -9 0; echo "PGRP mismatch $$ $p" >&2' bash "$@"; }
```

What it does:

- `setsid -w /bin/bash -c 'SCRIPT' bash "$@"` runs `SCRIPT` in a new process group
- `sleep 1 &` sets the timeout
- `. /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt && __git_ps1 "$@" &` runs the git prompt in parallel

  - `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` is for Ubuntu 22.04, change it if needed
- `wait -n;` waits for either the `sleep` or `__git_ps1` to return

  - The first one wins
- `p=$(/usr/bin/ps --no-headers -opgrp $$) && [ $$ = ${p:-x} ] &&` is just a safeguard to check `setsid` worked and we are really a process group leader

  - `$$` works here correctly, as we are within single quotes
- `kill -9 0` unconditionally kills the entire process group

  - all `git` that may still execute
  - including the `/bin/bash`
- `echo "PGRP mismatch $$ $p" >&2'` is never reached

  - This informs you that either `setsid` is a fake
  - or something else (`kill`?) did not work as expected

The safeguard protects against the case that `setsid` does not work as advertised.  Without your current shell might get killed, which would make it impossible to spawn an interactive shell.

> If you use the recipe and trust `setsid`, you probably do not need the safeguard, so `setsid` is the only non-bash-idiom this needs.

Comment: Bash 4 rocks. That is all.

Comment: This actually requires Bash 4.3 or newer.

`cc. The 'wait' builtin has a new '-n' option to wait for the next child to
    change status.`

From: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS

Comment: In bash 5.1, wait gets a -p argument which i think could make this even nicer, because you can detect which process has finished first, and handle success and timeout differently.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer "timelimit", which has a package at least in debian.

http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/

It is a bit nicer than the coreutils "timeout" because it prints something when killing the process, and it also sends SIGKILL after some time by default.

Comment: It does not seem to work pretty well :/ 
$ time timelimit -T2 sleep 10

real 0m10.003s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

Comment: Use -t2 not -T2. The big -T is the time from sending SIGTERM until sending SIGKILL.

Comment: I would like to add that timelimit 1.8 doesn't seams to works well with fork (`timelimit -t1 ./a_forking_prog` kill only one of the two process), but timeout works.

Comment: If you want timeout to print something when killing the process, just use the "-v" flag.

Answer (score 9):

See also the http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/timeout script the functionality of which has been integrated into newer coreutils

Comment: Neat, simple, uses TERM and not KILL. Nice! I had been exploring a trap/wait solution like this when I originally posed the question.

Comment: timeout returns 124 in case of an kill.

Answer (score 9):

*timeout* is probably the first approach to try. You may need notification or another command to execute if it times out. After quite a bit of searching and experimenting, I came up with this *bash* script:

```
if 
    timeout 20s COMMAND_YOU_WANT_TO_EXECUTE;
    timeout 20s AS_MANY_COMMANDS_AS_YOU_WANT;
then
    echo 'OK'; #if you want a positive response
else
    echo 'Not OK';
    AND_ALTERNATIVE_COMMANDS
fi
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Easy to read, easy to understand.  (It needs ` && \\`  joining each command, though, if you want to test whether ALL of your commands succeed.)

Answer (score 8):

Kinda hacky, but it works.  Doesn't work if you have other foreground processes (please help me fix this!)

```
sleep TIMEOUT & SPID=${!}; (YOUR COMMAND HERE; kill ${SPID}) & CPID=${!}; fg 1; kill ${CPID}
```

Actually, I think you can reverse it, meeting your 'bonus' criteria:

```
(YOUR COMMAND HERE & SPID=${!}; (sleep TIMEOUT; kill ${SPID}) & CPID=${!}; fg 1; kill ${CPID}) < asdf > fdsa
```

Comment: (ls -ltR /cygdrive/c/windows & SPID=${!}; (sleep 1s; kill ${SPID}) & CPID=${!}; fg 1; kill ${CPID}) >fdsa

Comment: @system PAUSE, set -m, I think.

Comment: I have job control (set -m) in the login shell. That's the 'm' in the himBH contents of $-, but it seems to disappear for the subshells. Possibly a Cygwin artifact. *grumble*

Comment: Don't use "fg" in scripts.  Read "help wait".

Comment: @strager, +1 for trying, and thanks. Your approach is very similar to others I've seen since I posted, and to some of the things I tried.

Answer (score 6):

Simple script with code clarity. Save to `/usr/local/bin/run`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run
# Run command with timeout $1 seconds.

# Timeout seconds
timeout_seconds="$1"
shift

# PID
pid=$$

# Start timeout
(
  sleep "$timeout_seconds"
  echo "Timed out after $timeout_seconds seconds"
  kill -- -$pid &>/dev/null
) &
timeout_pid=$!

# Run
"$@"

# Stop timeout
kill $timeout_pid &>/dev/null
```

Times out a command that runs too long:

```
$ run 2 sleep 10
Timed out after 2 seconds
Terminated
$
```

Ends immediately for a command that completes:

```
$ run 10 sleep 2
$
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already know the name of the program (let's assume `program`) to terminate after the timeout (as an example `3` seconds), I can contribute a simple and somewhat dirty alternative solution:

```
(sleep 3 && killall program) & ./program
```

This works perfectly if I call benchmark processes with system calls.

Comment: This kills other processes that happen to use the name and doesn't kill the process with the given name if it changes its name (e.g. by writing into `argv[0]`, perhaps with other hacks to make more room).

Comment: I found a variation of this handy when trying to stop docker containers after a certain amount of time.

The docker client didn't seem to accept TERM/INT/KILL in a way that would actually stop the container that was being run in the foreground.

So giving the container a name and using `(sleep 3 && docker stop <container>) &` worked nicely. Thanks!

Comment: yes it's dirt and limited, but can be improved like:
`{ sleep 5 && kill -9 $(ps -fe | grep "program" | grep $$ | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2); } & SLEEPPID=$!; bash -c "program" && kill -9 $SLEEPPID"`
This way, it will kill only jobs in current shell.

Answer (score 2):

There's also `cratimeout` by Martin Cracauer (written in C for Unix and Linux systems).

```
# cf. http://www.cons.org/cracauer/software.html
# usage: cratimeout timeout_in_msec cmd args
cratimeout 5000 sleep 1
cratimeout 5000 sleep 600
cratimeout 5000 tail -f /dev/null
cratimeout 5000 sh -c 'while sleep 1; do date; done'
```

Comment: "In particular, it preserves signal behavior." Nice to have that option!

Answer (score 2):

OS X doesn't use bash 4 yet, nor does it have /usr/bin/timeout, so here's a function that works on OS X without home-brew or macports that is similar to /usr/bin/timeout (based on Tino's answer).  Parameter validation, help, usage, and support for other signals are an exercise for reader.

```
# implement /usr/bin/timeout only if it doesn't exist
[ -n "$(type -p timeout 2>&1)" ] || function timeout { (
    set -m +b
    sleep "$1" &
    SPID=${!}
    ("${@:2}"; RETVAL=$?; kill ${SPID}; exit $RETVAL) &
    CPID=${!}
    wait %1
    SLEEPRETVAL=$?
    if [ $SLEEPRETVAL -eq 0 ] && kill ${CPID} >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
      RETVAL=124
      # When you need to make sure it dies
      #(sleep 1; kill -9 ${CPID} >/dev/null 2>&1)&
      wait %2
    else
      wait %2
      RETVAL=$?
    fi
    return $RETVAL
) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that does not rely on spawning a child process - I needed a standalone script which embedded this functionality. It also does a fractional poll interval, so you can poll quicker. timeout would have been preferred - but I'm stuck on an old server

```
# wait_on_command <timeout> <poll interval> command
wait_on_command()
{
    local timeout=$1; shift
    local interval=$1; shift
    $* &
    local child=$!

    loops=$(bc <<< "($timeout * (1 / $interval)) + 0.5" | sed 's/\..*//g')
    ((t = loops))
    while ((t > 0)); do
        sleep $interval
        kill -0 $child &>/dev/null || return
        ((t -= 1))
    done

    kill $child &>/dev/null || kill -0 $child &>/dev/null || return
    sleep $interval
    kill -9 $child &>/dev/null
    echo Timed out
}

slow_command()
{
    sleep 2
    echo Completed normally
}

# wait 1 sec in 0.1 sec increments
wait_on_command 1 0.1 slow_command

# or call an external command
wait_on_command 1 0.1 sleep 10
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution here, works perfectly on MacOS, does not depends [just] on bash (it runs fine on /bin/sh too) and it is very extremely precise! Thank you a lot for such code!

Answer (score 1):

The timeout command itself has a `--foreground` option. This lets the command interact with the user "when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt".

```
timeout --foreground the_command its_options
```

I think the questioner must have been aware of the very obvious solution of the `timeout` command, but asked for an alternate solution for this reason. `timeout` did not work for me when I called it using `popen`, i.e. 'not directly from the shell'. However, let me not assume that this may have been the reason in the questioner's case. Take a look at its [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

Comment: With `--foreground` Ctrl-C (SIGINT) will work, but won't kill any children process.

Comment: "I think the questioner must have been aware of the very obvious solution of the timeout command" -- No, when I asked 14 years ago, I was not aware of it. From other answers and comments, you can see that timeout was not available everywhere, at least not by default. But thank you for the mention of the --foreground option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in your script, put this in there:

```
parent=$$
( sleep 5 && kill -HUP $parent ) 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what this is doing?

Comment: A sub-process waits 5 seconds and then sends a hangup signal to the parent.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
timeout=10
interval=1
delay=3
(
    ((t = timeout)) || :

    while ((t > 0)); do
        echo "$t"
        sleep $interval
        # Check if the process still exists.
        kill -0 $$ 2> /dev/null || exit 0
        ((t -= interval)) || :
    done

    # Be nice, post SIGTERM first.
    { echo SIGTERM to $$ ; kill -s TERM $$ ; sleep $delay ; kill -0 $$ 2> /dev/null && { echo SIGKILL to $$ ; kill -s KILL $$ ; } ; }
) &

exec "$@"
```

Comment: @Tino Sorry I forgot why I changed the process termination line and why I thought this was important to share.  Too bad I did not write this down.  Perhaps, I found that I needed to pause before checking for a success of kill -s TERM.  The year 2008 script from the cook book seems to check for the process's state immediately after sending SIGTERM, possibly leading to an error trying to send SIGKILL to a process that died.

Answer (score 0):

I was presented with a problem to preserve the shell context and allow timeouts, the only problem with it is it will stop script execution on the timeout - but it's fine with the needs I was presented:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

safe_kill()
{
  ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $1 >/dev/null && kill ${2:-} $1
}

my_timeout()
{
  typeset _my_timeout _waiter_pid _return
  _my_timeout=$1
  echo "Timeout($_my_timeout) running: $*"
  shift
  (
    trap "return 0" USR1
    sleep $_my_timeout
    echo "Timeout($_my_timeout) reached for: $*"
    safe_kill $$
  ) &
  _waiter_pid=$!
  "$@" || _return=$?
  safe_kill $_waiter_pid -USR1
  echo "Timeout($_my_timeout) ran: $*"
  return ${_return:-0}
}

my_timeout 3 cd scripts
my_timeout 3 pwd
my_timeout 3 true  && echo true || echo false
my_timeout 3 false && echo true || echo false
my_timeout 3 sleep 10
my_timeout 3 pwd
```

with the outputs:

```
Timeout(3) running: 3 cd scripts
Timeout(3) ran: cd scripts
Timeout(3) running: 3 pwd
/home/mpapis/projects/rvm/rvm/scripts
Timeout(3) ran: pwd
Timeout(3) running: 3 true
Timeout(3) ran: true
true
Timeout(3) running: 3 false
Timeout(3) ran: false
false
Timeout(3) running: 3 sleep 10
Timeout(3) reached for: sleep 10
Terminated
```

of course I assume there was a dir called `scripts`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was maybe a bit different : I start a command via ssh on a remote machine and want to kill the shell and childs if the command hangs.

I now use the following :

```
ssh server '( sleep 60 && kill -9 0 ) 2>/dev/null & my_command; RC=$? ; sleep 1 ; pkill -P $! ; exit $RC'
```

This way the command returns 255 when there was a timeout or the returncode of the command in case of success

Please note that killing processes from a ssh session is handled different from an interactive shell. But you can also use the -t option to ssh to allocate a pseudo terminal, so it acts like an interactive shell

Answer (score -1):

Building on [@loup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096953/337735)...

If you want to timeout a process and silence the kill job/pid output, run:

```
( (sleep 1 && killall program 2>/dev/null) &) && program --version
```

This puts the backgrounded process into a subshell so you don't see the job output.

Answer (score -2):

A very simplistic way:

```
# command & sleep 5; pkill -9 -x -f "command"
```

with *pkill* (option **-f**) you can kill your specific command with arguments or specify -n to avoid kill old process.

Comment: You realize this is essentially what the OP has in his post and what he indicates he doesn't want, right? Because it always waits the full sleep delay.

Answer (score -3):

In 99% of the cases the answer is NOT to implement any timeout logic.  Timeout logic is in nearly any situation a red warning sign that something *else* is wrong and should be fixed *instead*.

Is your process hanging or breaking after n seconds sometimes?  Then find out why and fix that instead.

As an aside, to do strager's solution right, you need to use wait "$SPID" instead of fg 1, since in scripts you don't have job control (and trying to turn it on is stupid).  Moreover, fg 1 relies on the fact that you didn't start any other jobs previously in the script which is a bad assumption to make.

Comment: With access to 100% of the source (and most of the hardware, such as network switches), I would agree that there are probably better solutions than a timeout. But when a 'tlrbsf' is closed-source, binary only, sometimes you have to work around that limitation.

Comment: @lhunath, "in scripts you don't have job control (and trying to turn it on is stupid)" -- Please clarify here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @system PAUSE:  Reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script/690297#690297 is correct, I also commented on it.

Comment: lhunath, what you're saying makes no sense. there are tons of cases where timing out is a good option, e.g. anytime you have to go over the network.

Comment: An exception: you are writing test scripts to check if an *already running software* doesn't have a timeout problem.

Comment: One example is `traceroute` running forever in certain cases. Including, as of this writing, `traceroute example.com`.

Answer (score -5):

I have a cron job that calls a php script and, some times, it get stuck on php script. This solution was perfect to me.

I use:

```
scripttimeout -t 60 /script.php
```

Comment: What is `scripttimeout`?

Comment: not really a helpful answer on this, I think this can go as it is not explained at all.