# Stop process as soon as a file contains "Success"

Tags: shell

I'm trying to stop a long running process as soon as the file `/status` contains the string `Success`.

I tried this without success:

```
cat & while [ `grep -q Success /status` ]; do sleep 1; done; kill %1
```

`cat` is the long running process that needs to be stopped when `/status` contains `Success`.

Cheers

Comment: Is `cat` an example or is the real command? Also, who creates the file?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: @Robert @johnharris85 thanks for your comments, I edited the question.
`cat` is indeed the long running process that can be replaced by anything else really.

Comment: ```[ `grep -q Success /status` ]``` is always false, because you're looking at the **stdout** of `grep`, not its exit status, and the stdout of `grep -q` is (intentionally!) always empty.

Comment: BTW, use `cat & cat_pid=$!`, then later `kill "$cat_pid"` -- job control (`%1`) is only guaranteed to be available in interactive shells.

Comment: BTW -- is this file being appended to? Can it grow long? If so, continually re-`grep`ing from the beginning is very, *very* inefficient.

Comment: ...you might https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787575/using-tail-f-on-a-log-file-with-grep-in-bash-script informative, in terms of trying to build a better implementation.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate as the one pointed. Here is involved a question on how terminate a process too. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @Robert, if your point is that the question is too broad (incorporates multiple distinct scopes rather than being properly narrowed to one, as site guidelines request), I'll accept that point as valid -- but it *doesn't* argue for reopening.

Comment: @Robert, ...moreover, since one can have more than a single dupe flag now, that could be remedied by adding a question asking how to terminate a process as a second dupe target.

Comment: @Robert, ...and said remedy is performed; we're now *also* flagged as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369136/how-to-kill-a-background-process-created-in-a-script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for the information. The confusion started for me from the first version of this post, which lead me to think solutions docker-related. Anyway, as the question looks now it seems that you are totally right.