# Kill by bash id instead of PID

Tags: bash, kill

Can you kill the process int he bash script without knowing the PID, and only knowing the bash job ID (obtained with `jobs` for example)?

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 python
```

I can have multiple `python` executables running, so `killall python` is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `kill` only works for `PID`s. What I would recommend you is to keep the PID after running your script:

```
./some_script &
script_PID=$!
```

After that you can use `kill`as usual.

Comment: See: [You can kill by job number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624730/3776858).

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much