# How to cancel a curl request in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a script that hits an endpoint 50 times. After each of the requests I would like to cancel that request.

```
for i in $(eval echo {1..50})
do 
  curl --location --request GET 'localhost/endpoint' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' &

  cancel request?
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What are cancellationTokens? You created them, yes? We don't know how to use them or test them.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The implementation of cancellationTokens is outside of the scope of the question. I would like to cancel the curl request in the shell script. thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to kill the curl process?

Comment: Yes, but i would like the script to continue running. Ex execute each curl 50 times and kill each curl process 50 times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linux: kill background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624691/linux-kill-background-task)

Comment: Seems like i was able to integrate that into my script and have the desired results, thank you!

Comment: no need for an extra process, as `for i in {1..10} ; do echo "do something with $i" ; done` will also work.