# Bash `wait` command, waiting for more than 1 PID to finish execution

Tags: linux, bash, wait, pid

I recently posted a question asking if it was possible to [prevent PID's from being re-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359901/bash-is-it-possible-to-stop-a-pid-from-being-reused/40368941#40368941).

So far the answer appears to be no. (Which is fine.)

However, the user [Diego Torres Milano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236465/diego-torres-milano) added an answer to that question, and my question here is in regards to that answer.

Diego answered,

> If you are afraid of reusing PID's, which won't happen if you wait as
>   other answers explain, you can use
>
> ```
> echo 4194303 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
> ```
>
> to decrease your fear ;-)

I don't actually understand why Diego has used the number `4194303` here, but that's another question.

My understanding was that I had a problem with the following code:

```
for pid in "${PIDS[@]}"
do
    wait $pid
done
```

The problem being that I have multiple PIDs in an array, and that the for loop will run the `wait` command sequentially with each PID in the array, however I cannot predict that the processes will finish in the same order that their PIDs are stored in this array.

ie; the following *could* happen:

- Start waiting for PID in array index 0
- Process with PID in index 1 of array terminates
- New job(s) run on system, resulting in PID which is stored in index 1 of PID array being *reused for another process*
- `wait` terminates as PID in array index 0 exits
- Start waiting for PID in array index 0, *except this is now a different process and we have no idea what it is*
- The process which was run which re-used the PID which `wait` is currently waiting for *never* terminates. Perhaps it is the PID of a mail server or something which a system admin has started.
- `wait` keeps waiting until the next serious linux bug is found and the system is rebooted or there is a power outage

Diego said:

> which won't happen if you wait as other answers explain

ie; that the situation I have described above cannot happen.

Is Diego correct?

- If so, why can the situation I discribed above not occur?

Or is Diego not correct?

- If so, well, then I post a new question later today...

## Additional notes

It has occured to me that this question might be confusing, unless you are aware that the PID's are PID's of processes launched in the background. ie;

```
my_function &
PID="$!"
PIDS+=($PID)
```

Comment: Have you read the bash documentation for wait? It accepts more than one pid.

Comment: @BjornA. Yes I have. The documentation says it accepts 1 PID only.

Comment: Quote from (my) `man bash` :  `wait [-n] [n ...] Wait for each specified child process`

Comment: wait [-n] [n ...] Wait for each specified child process and return its termination status.  Each n may be a process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for.  If n is  not  given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero.  If the -n option is supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and returns its exit status.  If n specifies  a non-existent  process  or job, the return status is 127.  Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.

Comment: Okay thanks I misunderstood from reading this webpage: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: @Aaron Can I use an array as an argument to `wait`?

Comment: No, it's the shell parsing ability that comes into action here, you have to provide an IFS-separated list of PIDs. However, using `${array[@]}` could produce such a list.

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot wait for a pid that is  not a child of the current script/shell process - thus it's not possible to wait for a random pid that got reused elsewhere. The bash wait command also says: "If  n  is  not
              given, all currently active child processes are waited for" , i.e. you can call `wait` with no arguments.

Comment: Also consider using `wait` without arguments as proposed in your other question if you want to wait on all the process you've spawned from your main script. It would eliminate the need to maintain a PID list.

Comment: Most of this question has already been answered in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360239/1640661

Comment: @nos that's fine I only intend to wait for child processes

Comment: @Aaron Thanks I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan If it was then it wasn't clear to me

Comment: @Aaron So if I convert my PIDs to a space separated string of PIDs, ie; a string, then that will work?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to wait for a specific subset of your child processes with a single wait, avoiding to use a loop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's turning into a chat forum in the comments.  Maybe this discussion could be moved to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @user3728501, ...btw, the ABS is generally poorly-regarded as a reference -- it's infrequently updated and often showcases bad practices in examples. Consider the bash-hackers wiki (its page on `wait` is [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/wait)), or the Wooledge wiki [SignalTrap](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap) page.

Answer (score 46):

Let's go through your options.

### Wait for all background jobs, unconditionally

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    cmd &
done
wait
```

This has the benefit of being simple, but you can't keep your machine busy. If you want to start new jobs as old ones complete, you can't. You machine gets less and less utilized until all the background jobs complete, at which point you can start a new batch of jobs.

Related is the ability to wait for a subset of jobs by passing multiple arguments to `wait`:

```
unrelated_job &
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  cmd & pids+=($!)
done
wait "${pids[@]}"   # Does not wait for unrelated_job, though
```

### Wait for individual jobs in arbitrary order

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
   cmd & pids+=($!)
done

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
   wait "$pid"
   # do something when a job completes
done
```

This has the benefit of letting you do work after a job completes, but
still has the problem that jobs *other* than `$pid` might complete first, leaving your machine underutilized until `$pid` actually completes. You  do, however, still get the exit status for each individual job, even if it completes before you actually wait for it.

### Wait for the *next* job to complete (`bash` 4.3 or later)

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
   cmd & pids+=($!)
done

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
   wait -n
   # do something when a job completes
done
```

Here, you can wait until *a* job completes, which means you can keep your machine as busy as possible. The only problem is, you don't necessarily know *which* job completed, without using `jobs` to get the list of active processes and comparing it to `pids`.

### Other options?

The shell by itself is not an ideal platform for doing job distribution, which is why there are a multitude of programs designed for managing batch jobs: `xargs`, `parallel`, `slurm`, `qsub`, etc.

Comment: Wow this is an awesome answer, thanks so much for this

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **Bash 5.1**, there is now an additional way of waiting for and handling multiple background jobs thanks to the introduction of `wait -p`.

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for ((i=0; i < 10; i++)); do
    secs=$((RANDOM % 10)); code=$((RANDOM % 256))
    (sleep ${secs}; exit ${code}) &
    echo "Started background job (pid: $!, sleep: ${secs}, code: ${code})"
done

while true; do
    wait -n -p pid; code=$?
    [[ -z "${pid}" ]] && break
    echo "Background job ${pid} finished with code ${code}"
done
```

The novelty here is that you now know *exactly which one* of the background jobs finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but the scenario presented where a deferred `wait` waits for some random unrelated process due to pid collision hasn't been directly addressed.

It's not possible at the kernel level. The way it works there is that prior to the parent process calling `wait(2)`¹, the child process *still exists*. Because the child still exists, linux will run out of pids rather than reuse it. This manifests at times with so called zombie or "defunct" processes - these are children which have exited but have yet to be "reaped" by their parent.

Now, at the shell level you don't have to call `wait(1)`¹ for child processes to be reaped - `bash` does this automatically. I haven't confirmed, but when you run `wait $pid` for a child pid which exited long ago, I would wager `bash` realises it has already reaped that child and returns the information immediately rather than waiting for anything.

¹ the `wait(N)` notation is a convention used to disambiguate between API layers - N refers to the section of the manual a command/function is located in. In this case we have:

- `wait(2)`: the syscall - see `man 2 wait`
- `wait(1)`: the shell command - see `man 1 wait` or `help wait`

If you want to know what lives in each manual section, try `man N intro`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It works without having to memoize the backgrounded PIDs (by using `jobs -p`), preserves exit codes, and exits early if one task fails.

```
while (($(jobs -p | wc -l) > 0)); do
  if wait -n; then
    :
  else
    ret=$?
    jobs -p | xargs -n1 kill 2>/dev/null
    wait
    exit $ret
  fi
done
```

The `if wait -n; then :` ensures that you can still use `ERREXIT` (`!` masks the exit code).

A oneliner that skips the early exit would be

```
while read -r pid; do wait "$pid"; done < <(jobs -p)
```

As to your concerns:

- `jobs` only lists background processes under the current process.
- `wait` cannot wait on PIDs that aren't owned by the current process.