# Waiting for the last 10 parallel started jobs to finish in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have the following bash script, which starts a program several times in parallel and passes a control variable to each execution. 
The program is utilizes several resources, so after it was started 10 times in parallel I want to wait till the last 10 started, are finished.

I am currently doing this very roughly, by just waiting after 10 iterations for the longest time possible that 10 parallel started programs are finished.

Is there a straight forward way to implement this behavior?

```
steps=$((500/20))  
echo $steps
START=0

for((i=START;i < steps; i++))
do
        for((j=START;j < steps;j++))
        do
                for((k=START;k < steps;k++))
                do
                        n=$(($j*steps +$k))
                        idx=$(($i*$steps*$steps + $n))


                        if ! ((idx % 10)); then
                                echo "waiting for the last 10 programs"
                                sleep 10
                        else 
                                 ./someprogram $idx &
                        fi
                done
        done
done
```

Comment: If you want to track whether the programs succeeded or failed, you'll want to store their PIDs. An associative array mapping between PID and the `idx` is particularly useful, since that lets you know which `idx`s succeeded and failed.

Comment: BTW, this approach as a whole is generally quite inefficient -- you usually have a bunch of wasted CPU time between when the first program in a batch finishes and when the last one does. Better off using something like `for ((k=start; k<end; k++)); do printf '%s\0' "$k"; done | xargs -0  -P 10 -n 1 ./someprogram`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I saw that post and I am not quite sure if it is relatable for my case due to using an asynchronous device, which relies on the waiting time to finish up the jobs. However, does your answer already provide the wait for the program or is ist just for starting?

Comment: Which one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160/parallelize-bash-script-with-maximum-number-of-processes calls for an answer that discusses `wait`, yes, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377623/bash-wait-command-waiting-for-more-than-1-pid-to-finish-execution is *explicitly about* the `wait` command. As for "your answer", while I'm around in the bash tag a lot, I don't believe I have answers on either of those questions as of this writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you already have a code in place to check the 10th iteration (`idx % 10`), the `wait` builtin seems perfect. From the docs:

> `wait: wait [-n] [id ...]`
>
> [...] Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
>       job specification, and reports its termination status.  **If ID is not
>       given, waits for all currently active child processes**, and the return
>       status is zero.

So, by `wait`ing each time `idx % 10 == 0`, you are actually waiting for all previous child processes to finish. And if you are not spawning anything else than `someprogram`, then you'll be waiting for those (up to 10) last to finish.

Your script with `wait`:

```
#!/bin/bash

steps=$((500/20))  
START=0

for ((i=START; i<steps; i++)); do
    for ((j=START; j<steps; j++)); do
        for ((k=START; k<steps; k++)); do
            idx=$((i*steps*steps + j*steps + k))

            if ! ((idx % 10)); then
                wait
            else 
                ./someprogram $idx &
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Also, notice you don't have to use `$var` (dollar prefix) inside arithmetic expansion `$((var+1))`.

---

I'm assuming above your actual script does some additional processing before calling `someprogram`, but if all you need is to call `someprogram` on consecutive indexes, 10 instances at a time, you might consider using `xargs` or [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

For example, with `xargs`:

```
seq 0 1000 | xargs -n1 -P10 ./someprogram
```

or, with additional arguments to `someprogram`:

```
seq 0 1000 | xargs -n1 -P10 -I{} ./someprogram --option --index='{}' someparam
```

With GNU `parallel`:

```
seq 0 1000 | parallel -P10 ./someprogram '{}'

seq 0 1000 | parallel -P10 ./someprogram --option --index='{}' someparam
```