# Bash files: run process in parallel and stop when one is over

Tags: bash

I would like to start two C codes from a bash file in parallel and the second one stops when the first one has finished.
The instruction wait expects both processes to stop which is not what I would like to do.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: How do you want to stop the second one? with "kill" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) can do this kind of job. Check [termination](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Termination) section, it can shutdown down remaining processes based on the exit code (either success or failure:

```
parallel -j2 --halt now,success=1 ::: 'cmd1 args' 'cmd2 args'
```

When one of the job finishes successfully, it will send TERM signal to the other jobs (if jobs are not terminated it forces using KILL signal).

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this command with GNU parallel 20130922, but and following the tutorial that you indicate in the link but get: Value "now,success=1" invalid for option halt (number expected)

Comment: In version *20161222* (Ubuntu 17.04 default version) works. It seems that the change was introduced [during 2015](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/commit/?id=8110572719461a6019b8f4c22d5ebf43f65cfbe6). Try using *--halt -2*, which seems to be the previous format.

Comment: Ok, that works. And instead of stopping when the first one succeed, it stops when the first one fails. Then I introduced an error at the end of the command that I know will finish first.

Comment: If you think this Answer responds to your question, mark it as Accepted. That way it will be removed from Unanswered questions list. More on: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

With `$!` you get the pid of the last command executed in parallel. See some nice examples here: [Bash `wait` command, waiting for more than 1 PID to finish execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377623/bash-wait-command-waiting-for-more-than-1-pid-to-finish-execution)

For your peculiar problem I imagine something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

command_master() {
    echo -e "Command_master"
    sleep 1
}
command_tokill() {
    echo -e "Command_tokill"
    sleep 10
}

command_master & pid_master=($!)
command_tokill & pid_tokill=($!)
wait "$pid_master"
kill "$pid_tokill"
```

Comment: Thank you. The process to kill is a C code which I'd like to tell that it is going to be killed and have time to close files before. Basically send a signal from the master to the process to kill such that it enters a loop and does final operations before being killed. Is that possible?

Comment: For example, when the master is done, send an integer to the C file, runMe.c with runMe 1 such that it enters a final loop in the C code.

Comment: I understand your problem. Unfortunately, I haven't a clean bash solution to propose. For a clean solution, one must take care of some synchronizations and I do not know if bash is really convenient for that. In my example, for instance, there is no protection against the following scenario: the "toKill" process ends before "master" process. If during wait "$pid_master", the OS starts another process with the same PID as the previous "toKill" one, then the bash instruction kill "$pid_tokill" will kill the wrong process.

Comment: this is quite unlikely as AFAIK on  *nix  PID are generated in an incremental way (once a limit is reached, allocation restarts at zero and again increases, skipping still existing PID).  But the solution is not clean....

Answer (score 1):

`wait -n` is what you are looking for. It waits for the next job to finish. You can then have a list of the PIDs of the remaining jobs with `jobs -p` if you want to kill them.

Answer (score 1):

```
prog1 & pids=( $! )
prog2 & pids+=( $! )

wait -n

kill "${pids[@]}"
```

This requires `bash`.

The two programs are started as background jobs, and the shell waits for one of them to exit.

When this happens, `kill` is used to terminate both processes (this will cause an error since one of them is already dead).