# Shell: how to run two scripts A and B in parallel and stop B when A is over

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a shell script `A.sh` whose content is:

```
sleep 2
echo "A: 2s"
sleep 2
echo "A: 4s"
sleep 2
echo "A: 6s"
```

I also have a shell script `B.sh` whose content is:

```
sleep 2
echo "B: 2s"
sleep 2
echo "B: 4s"
sleep 2
echo "B: 6s"
sleep 2
echo "B: 8s"
sleep 2
echo "B: 10s"
```

When I hope to run A and B in parallel, I created a script `C.sh` whose content is:

```
sh A.sh &
sh B.sh &
wait
```

The output is:

```
B: 2s
A: 2s
A: 4s
B: 4s
A: 6s
B: 6s
B: 8s
B: 10s
```

In this way A and B can run in parallel. Now I have **one more requirement** that is I hope to stop B when A is over. I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015427/bash-files-run-process-in-parallel-and-stop-when-one-is-over) and modified `C.sh` to:

```
parallel -j2 --halt now,success=1 ::: 'sh A.sh' 'sh B.sh'
```

The output is:

```
A: 2s
A: 4s
A: 6s
parallel: This job succeeded:
sh A.sh
```

It seems B is not running in this way. Can anyone advise me what is the correct way to ***run two scripts A and B in parallel and stop B when A is over***?

Comment: I think it is running, but output is grouped by job by default, try `--linebuffer` Maybe also add `--tag` to see what comes from where.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi I think you are right. I can see the outputs if they are redirected to files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell adding `--linebuffer` also helps. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I wasn't at a proper machine earlier, but have put it as a normal answer now so folks can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is running, but output is grouped by job by default, so you won't see the output from B till A is finished but when A finishes, the whole **GNU Parallel** process exits.

Try switching to line-buffered output:

```
parallel --linebuffer sh ::: [AB].sh
```

Answer (score 5):

> to run two scripts A and B in parallel and stop B when A is over?

So do just that.

```
sh B.sh &
b_pid=$!
{
    sh A.sh 
    kill "$b_pid"
} &
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a sufficiently modern bash (eg, this does not work in 3.2.5.7, but it does in 5.0.16, so it was introduced sometime between those), you can do:

```
a.sh &
b.sh &
wait -n
kill -- -$$
```

This waits until either process terminates and then sends a SIGTERM to all the jobs in the process group.  Note, this will send the SIGTERM to *all* processes in the group, including the main script, so you may need to handle that.  If you want to restrict the jobs to which the signal is sent, run them in their own process group and send the signal appropriately.