# Bash wait command ignoring specified process IDs

Tags: bash, shell

```
DIRECTORIES=( group1 group2 group3 group4 group5 )
PIDS=()

function GetFileSpace() {
    shopt -s nullglob
    TARGETS=(/home/${1}/data/*)
    for ITEM in "${TARGETS[@]}"
    do
            # Here we launch du on a user in the background
            # And then add their process id to PIDS
            du -hs $ITEM >> ./${1}_filespace.txt &
            PIDS+=($!)
    done
}

# Here I launch function GetFileSpace for each group.
for GROUP in "${DIRECTORIES[@]}"
do
    echo $GROUP
    # Store standard error to collect files with bad permissions
    GetFileSpace $GROUP 2>> ./${GROUP}_permission_denied.txt &
done

for PID in "${PIDS[@]}"
do
    wait $PID
done

echo "Formatting Results..."
# The script will after this, but it isn't relevant.
```

I am trying to write a script that monitors storage volume and file permissions of individual users across 5 groups.

```
|_home          # For additional reference to understand my code,
  |_group1      # directories are laid out like this
  | |_data
  |   |_user1
  |   |_user2
  |   |_user3
  |
  |_group2
    |_data
      |_user4
      |_user5
```

First, I use a loop to iteratively launch a function, `GetFileSpace`, for each group in `DIRECTORIES`. This function then runs `du -sh` for each user found within a group.

To speed up this whole process, I launch each instance of `GetFileSpace` and the subsequent `du -sh` sub processes in the background with  `&`. This makes it so everything can run pretty much simultaneously, which takes much less time.

My issue is that after I launch these processes **I want my script to wait for every background instance of `du -sh` to finish before moving on to the next step**.

To do this, I have tried to collect process IDs after each task is launched within the array `PIDS`. Then I try to loop through the array and wait for each PID until all sub-processes finish. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The script correctly launches `du -sh` for each user, but then immediately tries to move on to the next step, breaking.

**My question then, is why does my script not wait for my background tasks to finish and how can I implement this behavior?**

As a final note, I have tried several other methods to accomplish this from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377623/bash-wait-command-waiting-for-more-than-1-pid-to-finish-execution), but haven't been able to get them working either.

Comment: a simple `wait` without specifying any PID didn't work?

Comment: I believe `wait` by itself does work. My problem was that I was running my function in the background not just my `du -sh` processes as @KamilCuk noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetFileSpace ... &
```

You are running the whole function as a subproces. So it `immediately tries to move on to the next step` and `PID` is unset, cause it beeing set in subprocess.

Do not run it in the background.

```
GetFileSpace ...   # no & on the end.
```

Notes: Consider using `xargs` or GNU `parallel`. Prefer lower case for script local variables. Quote variable expansions. Use shellcheck to check for such errors.

```
work() {
   tmp=$(du -hs "$2")
   echo "$tmp" >> "./${1}_filespace.txt"
}
export -f work
for i in "${directories[@]}"; do
   printf "$i %s\n" /home/${1}/data/*
done | xargs -n2 -P$(nproc) bash -c 'work "$@"' _
```

Note that when job is I/O bound, running multiple processes (escpecially without no upper bound) doesn't really help much, if it's on one disc.