# difference between running shell command directly and from shell script sh file

Tags: java, shell, background-process

I have a `java program` in which I am reading from stdin

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
byte[] b = new byte[1];
int cmd = bis.read(b);
System.out.println("Read command: " + new String(b));
```

And a `shell script` to start-stop this program

```
'start')
if [ -p myfifo ]; then
    rm myfifo
    rm myfifo-cat-pid
fi
mkfifo myfifo
cat > myfifo &
echo $! > myfifo-cat-pid
java -jar lib/myJar.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 0<myfifo &
echo `date +%D-%T` $! >> process.pid
echo "Started process: "$!
;;

'stop')
echo 0 > myfifo
echo "Stopped process: "
rm myfifo
;;
```

When I run commands in start one by one the program waits until i echo on fifo. But when I run it from .sh file it immediately reads from stdin. Dont understand what is the difference between if run a command directly on command prompt and if I make a .sh file and run it then

Comment: What is read from `stdin` if you run the .sh file? What is output on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not on the `Java` side, but instead on the fact that your shell handles differently the job control when launching a script. From `man bash`:

```
JOB CONTROL
   Job  control  refers  to  the ability to selectively stop (suspend) the
   execution of processes and continue (resume) their execution at a later
   point.   A  user  typically  employs  this  facility via an interactive
   interface supplied jointly by the operating  system  kernel's  terminal
   driver and bash.
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script), by default job control is disabled in a script.

When `cat > myfifo &` is executed in an interactive shell, it remains in "Stopped" mode waiting to be put in foreground again (with `fg`). When launched in a script, instead, job control is disabled so, as soon as `cat` tries to read from the (detached) terminal, it exists, closing the pipe (and your `Java` process reads `EOF`).

If you use `set -m` at the top of your shell script (hence enabling forcefully job control), you should see a consistent behavior.

```
set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]
  -m      Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled.  This option is on by
          default for interactive shells on systems  that  support  it
          (see JOB CONTROL above).  Background processes run in a sep‐
          arate process group and a line containing their exit  status
          is printed upon their completion.
```

Comment: where to use set -m i mean in header??

Comment: Before you launch any command with `&`; that is, probably it's best at the beginning of the script.

Comment: i have added first command as set -m... it is making no difference :(

Comment: Which shell are you using? If it's not Bash, then probably you shell does not support `set -m`.