# BASH script suspend/continue a process within script

Tags: bash

In my bash script I am writing, I am trying to start a process (sleep) in the background and then suspend it.  Finally, the process with be finished.  For some reason through, when I send the kill command with the stop signal, it just keeps running as if it received nothing.  I can do this from the command line, but the bash script is not working as intended.

```
sleep 15&
pid=$!
kill -s STOP $pid
jobs
kill -s CONT $pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it work by enabling 'monitor mode' in your script: `set -m`

Please see [why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script) for further information

Comment: Thank you very much!  I could not figure out why I could do it from the terminal, but not inside the script.