# starting a new process group from bash script

Tags: bash, unix, process, signals, freebsd

I basically want to run a script (which calls more scripts) in a new process group so that I can send signal to all the processes called by the script.

In Linux, I found out setsid helps me in doing that, but this is not available on FreeBSD.

Syntax for setsid (provided by util-linux-ng).

```
setsid /path/to/myscript
```

I, however learnt that session and process group are not the same. But starting a new session also solves my problem.

Comment: If you can compile C code, source for a setsid program for FreeBSD is at http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2011-February/034433.html .

Answer (score 19):

Sessions and groups are not the same thing. Let's make things clean:

A session consists of one or more process groups, and can have a controlling terminal. When the session has a controlling terminal, the session has, at any moment, exactly one foreground process group and one or more background process groups. In such a scenario, all terminal-generated signals and input is seen by every process in the foreground process group.

Also, when a session has a controlling terminal, the shell process is usually the session leader, dictating which process group is the foreground process group (implicitly making the other groups background process groups). Processes in a group are usually put there by a linear pipeline. For example, `ls -l | grep a | sort` will typically create a new process group where `ls`, `grep` and `sort` live.

Shells that support job control (which also requires support by the kernel and the terminal driver), as in the case of bash, create a new process group for each command invoked -- and if you invoke it to run in the background (with the `&` notation), that process group is not given the control of the terminal, and the shell makes it a background process group (and the foreground process group remains the shell).

So, as you can see, you almost certainly don't want to create a session in this case. A typical situation where you'd want to create a session is if you were daemonizing a process, but other than that, there is usually not much use in creating a new session.

You can run the script as a background job, as I mentioned, this will create a new process group. Since `fork()` inherits the process group ID, every process executed by the script will be in the same group. For example, consider this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm | grep ".*"
```

This prints something like:

```
  PID  PPID  PGID COMMAND
11888 11885 11888 bash
12343 11888 12343 execute.sh
12344 12343 12343 ps
12345 12343 12343 grep
```

As you can see, `execute.sh`, `ps` and `grep` are all on the same process group (the value in `PGID`).

So all you want is:

```
/path/to/myscript &
```

Then you can check the process group ID of `myscript` with `ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm | grep myscript`. To send a signal to the group, use `kill` with the *negative* of the process group ID (`PGID` is the `PID` of the leader of the group). A signal sent to a group is delivered to every process in that group. In the above example, to send `SIGTERM` to every process started by `execute.sh`, including the script itself, you would use `kill -- -12343`. (Note that sending a signal to the whole group is different from sending a signal to just the group leader: `kill 12343` and `kill -- -12343` are different!)

Comment: I want to call my script (lets say script-1) from a main script. And I want this script to be run under a new process group. Calling script-1 in the background does not start it under new process group.

Comment: Running command on the background will put it in another group. However, if you want to run something that e.g. uses `read`builtin of `bash`, is there a way to start such a script in a new process group? The reason I would like to have new process group is that SIGINT would be delivered only that group in case Ctrl+C is pressed.

Comment: "job control is by default turned off in non-interactive mode" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/690297/18096) and only, it seems, when job control is enabled do background pipelines get their own process group

Answer (score 3):

Using FreeBSD you may try using the `script` command that will internally execute the `setsid` command.

```
stty -echo -onlcr   # avoid added \r in output
script -q /dev/null /path/to/myscript
stty echo onlcr
# sync  # ... if terminal prompt does not return
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly answer, but is an alternative approach based on names.

You can have a common part of name for all process. For example we have **my_proc_group_29387172** part for all the following processes:

```
-rwxrwxr-x.   my_proc_group_29387172_microservice_1
-rwxrwxr-x.   my_proc_group_29387172_microservice_2
-rwxrwxr-x.   my_proc_group_29387172_data_dumper
```

Spawn all of them (and as much as you want):

```
ADDR=1 ./my_proc_group_29387172_microservice_1
ADDR=2 ./my_proc_group_29387172_microservice_1
ADDR=3 ./my_proc_group_29387172_microservice_2
./my_proc_group_29387172_data_dumper
```

When you want to kill all processes you can use **pkill** command (pattern kill) or **killall** with **--regexp**  parameter:

```
pkill my_proc_group_29387172
```

**Benefit :)** - you can start as many process as you want at any time (or any day) from any script.

**Drawback :(** - you can kill innocent processes if they has common part of name with your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

### Use job control

You can temporarily enable **job control** in bash with `set -m`. When it is enabled, every child process is created in a separate process group. But **job control** also enables some more features:

- reporting when a jobs gets terminated
- activation of `Ctrl+Z`, `Ctrl+Y` shortcuts

And probably something else, which might not be desired in a script. Therefore you can disable **job control** right after the child process is forked:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -m
/path/to/myscript &
set +m
```

This works with the compound commands as well, for example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -m
{
    while true; do
        /bin/some_server
    done
} &
set +m
server_pgid=$!

...

kill -- -$server_pgid
```

In this example `/bin/some_server` process will be killed as well as the wrapper process. Note that the process group killing method is used here (PGID is prefixed with `-`).

You can read more about the **job control** in the bash manual page.

### Determining PGID of the specific PID

To determine the process group id (PGID) which the process belongs to, you can use this command:

```bash
ps j $PID
```

which prints detailed info about the specified PID, including PGID. In scripts you can use command `ps ho pgid:1 $PID` which only prints PGID value, for example like this:

```bash
PGID=`ps ho pgid:1 $PID`
```

here `h` disables headers in `ps` output, `o pgid` sets output of PGID field only and `:1` specifies the width of the column, without it small PGIDs will be prefixed with spaces