# sudo ignores SIGTERM sent from same script

Tags: linux, bash, signals, sudo, kill

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sleep 60 &
sudo_pid=$!
sudo kill $sudo_pid
```

I'd expect that after the `kill`, the `sudo` command and its child `sleep` process would be terminated, but they aren't, as shown by this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sleep 60 &
sudo_pid=$!
sudo kill $sudo_pid

if ps -p $sudo_pid > /dev/null; then
    sudo kill $sudo_pid
else
    echo "No sudo process running"
    exit 1
fi

if ps -p $sudo_pid > /dev/null; then
    echo "sudo (pid $sudo_pid) is still running"
    ps -F $sudo_pid
else
    echo "sudo successfully killed"
fi
```

Which yields this output when I run it (with `sudo` creds cached):

```
jon@ubuntu:~$ ./so.sh 
sudo (pid 46199) is still running
UID         PID   PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root      46199  46198  0 14764  3984   3 13:37 pts/0    S+     0:00 sudo sleep 60
```

After the script completes (and `sudo sleep 60` is still running), it *is* possible to kill it with the identical command:

```
jon@ubuntu:~$ ps -F 46199
UID         PID   PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root      46199      1  0 14764  3984   3 13:37 pts/0    S      0:00 sudo sleep 60

jon@ubuntu:~$ sudo kill 46199

jon@ubuntu:~$ ps -F 46199
UID         PID   PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD

jon@ubuntu:~$
```

I notice that after the `so.sh` script exits, the parent process ID for `sudo sleep 60` has changed from the script to the `init` process, which I think is significant. It's also possible to successfully kill the `sudo sleep 60` process from a different shell while the `so.sh` script is still running.

I also noticed that using `sudo kill -ABRT` in the script (as opposed to `kill`'s default `SIGTERM`) does successfully kill the `sudo` process, so I assume that is has something to do with the way `sudo` handles `SIGTERM`. However, based on the man page, I don't think it should be doing anything special:

```
Signal handling
  When the command is run as a child of the sudo process, sudo will relay
  signals it receives to the command.  The SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals are
  only relayed when the command is being run in a new pty or when the sig‐
  nal was sent by a user process, not the kernel.  This prevents the com‐
  mand from receiving SIGINT twice each time the user enters control-C.
```

The only special handling of `SIGTERM` mentioned in the man page is for `signals that were sent by the command it is running`; not the case here. Furthermore, I changed the `ps -F` in above script to `ps -o blocked,caught,ignored,pending` and it output

```
sudo (pid 46429) is still running
         BLOCKED           CAUGHT          IGNORED          PENDING
0000000000000000 00000001800b7a07 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

Which seems to indicate that SIGTERM isn't being blocked or ignored, so why isn't the `sudo sleep 60` process getting terminated?

I've come up with several workarounds (`setsid`, `sudo -b`, killing the child `sleep` process rather than the parent `sudo` process), so I'm not looking for alternate approach answers. I just want to understand what's going on here.

In case it matters:

```
jon@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jon@ubuntu:~$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.20p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.20p2
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.20p2
```

Answer (score 5):

I found following comments in source code of sudo

```
  /*  
 * Do not forward signals sent by a process in the command's process
 * group, as we don't want the command to indirectly kill itself.
 * For example, this can happen with some versions of reboot that
 * call kill(-1, SIGTERM) to kill all other processes.
 */
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for that response. That is notably missing from the docs.

Answer (score 5):

If you will change your `sudo kill $sudo_pid` to `setsid sudo kill $sudo_pid` it will work.

Found this here: [starting a new process group from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758424/starting-a-new-process-group-from-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

The signal mask bit for any given signal is:

```
(1ULL << ((signal_number) - 1))
```

(for standard signals in the 1-32 range anyway; additional signals are in the "real time" signal sets and are handled somewhat differently, though the same concept applies).  So the interesting part of the `CAUGHT` mask is:

```
...7a07
```

which is (+ for caught, - for not caught, in the expanded part):

```
xxx7: signals 1, 2, 3, but not 4: +SIGHUP  +SIGINT  +SIGQUIT -SIGILL
xx0x: not 5-8:                    -SIGTRAP -SIGABRT -SIGBUS  -SIGFPE
xaxx: not 9, 10, not 11, 12:      -SIGKILL +SIGUSR1 -SIGSEGV +SIGUSR2
7xxx: 13, 14, 15, not 16:         +SIGPIPE +SIGALRM +SIGTERM -SIGSTKFLT
```

(you can continue decoding the rest if you like; see `/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h` for the Linux-specific signal numbers; note that the numeric definitions differ on OSX and BSD but the technique is the same: caught or blocked or whatever signals are represented as 1-bits in the mask).

So, this means `sudo` is catching `SIGTERM` but not catching `SIGABRT`.  The fact that `SIGTERM` is not passed on must have something to do with the `sudo` code itself.  The source (`apt-get source sudo`) has some rather complicated code for doing the signal handling, including some interesting debug tricks you can turn on in the sudo config file to help you track down what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on the signals! It makes sense that `sudo` is catching `SIGTERM` since it doesn't propagate that signal when it originates with `sudo`'s child process. I guess I'll have to dig into the source (thanks for that apt pointer) if I really want to know.