# How to run "jobs" command in shell script?

Tags: shell

I created the file `test.sh` which contains `ls -ltr & jobs` command. When I run it, it gives me the output of `ls -ltr`, but for `jobs` command it doesn't give me anything, not even an error.4

Whats wrong?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: @Vadim, `&` is perfectly valid for `bash`, it's the "run in background" statement terminator, similar to `;` but without waiting. In fact, it may be the OP is expecting the `jobs` to actually show the `ls` running in parallel.

Comment: In programming, details are very important.  To get a good answer, you need to show us what your script actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`jobs` is an interactive command -- it is not meant to be used from scripts, and doesn't do anything useful in a script (but it could plausibly do something useful in a shell function called from an interactive session; so disabling it in code isn't really appropriate, either).

To keep track of background jobs, collect their PID:s when you start them.

```
ls -ltr &
pid=$!
printf 'pid: %s' "$pid"
```

Comment: As an aside, [`ls` should usually not be called from scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), either; but I understand it's used as a simple example placeholder here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script