# Bash: Terminate on Timeout/File Overflow while Executing Command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, timeout, overflow

I'm writing a mock-grading script in bash. It's supposed to execute a C program which will give some output (which I redirect to a file.) I'm trying to (1) make it timeout after a certain duration and also (2) terminate if the output file reaches a certain file size limit. Not sure how to go about either of these. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a GNU coreutil command `timeout` to do timeouts.

Investigate `ulimit -f 32` to set the maximum file size (to 16 KiB; it counts in 512 byte blocks).

Objection:

> ulimit is [*not*] suitable because I have to create other files as well. I need to limit only one of them.

Counter: Unless the program must create a big file and a little file and you have to limit just the little file, you can use a sub-shell to good effect:

```
(
ulimit -f 32
timeout 10m -- command arg >file
)
```

The limit on file size is restricted to the commands in the sub-shell (which is marked by the pair of parentheses).

Comment: I don't think ulimit is suitable because I have to create other files as well. I need to limit only one of them.

Comment: This solution works well for the file limit condition. However, I can't use the coreutils (the machines this has to run on don't have them installed.) Is there another option for timeout?

Comment: @Chris, you could start another script in the background that sleeps nnn seconds and then sends a signal to the parent PID, which the parent could handle with `trap`. Racey, but it should work.

Comment: GNU coreutils are things like 'ls' - and current versions of coreutils (8.4 verified present; 6.12 verified absent) contain `timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `timeout` command eg

```
timeout -s 9 5s ./c_program > file
```

to check file size, you can stat the file, then do `if/else`

```
limit=1234 #bytes
size=$(stat -c "%s" file)
if [ "$size"  -gt "$limit" ] ;then
  exit
fi
```

see also [here](http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3) if you can't use these GNU tools, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay) for some other inspirations.

Answer (score 0):

This starts *yourcommand*, redirecting output via *dd* to *youroutputfile* and putting a limit of 10000000 bytes on it: *dd* will terminate and SIGPIPE will be sent to *yourcommand*

```
yourcommand | dd of=youroutputfile bs=1 count=10000000 &
```

This will wait 5 seconds and kill *yourcommand* if not already terminated:

```
sleep 5
kill %yourcommand
```