# Stop Search param in directories by grep immediately after param match

Tags: bash, grep

I use the following command to find under /var some param in my script

grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep   -wq  "param"

my problem is that: after  grep find the param in file
grep continue to search until all searches under /var/* will completed

How to perform stop immediately after grep match the param word

For example when I run the:
grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep   -wq  "param"

grep find the param after one second.

But grep continue to  Search  other same  param on other files and its take almost 30 seconds

How to stop the grep immediately after param match?

THX

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep has a -m, --max-count option:

```
$ grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep -wq -m1 "param"
```

Questions: why the double grep? why try to expand with * if you are making grep recursive?  consider also -s to silent annoying error messages (I'd recommend alto to use -n to print matching line, but for the -q it seems you want no output):

```
$ grep -qsRw -m1 "param" /var
```

Comment: THX the grep -qsRw -m1 "param" /var is very good for my case

But I have other quastion
how to add time out to grep 
for example after 20 second I need to break from grep or command
how to do that according my first quastion?
Yael

Comment: Of course grep does not manage timeouts, this is an orthogonal issue. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay

Comment: ( /path/to/slow command with options ) & sleep 5 ; kill $! this not good for me because I check the $? of the grep what can I to do, seems I have abig problem -:(

Comment: Yael, this command is part of *the question*, he does not like it so he asks for alternatives. There are plenty of good answers there. For example you can use "timeout" (coreutils package): : timeout 2 mycommand

Comment: maybe other solution
for example to see which proccess is grep and then to kill it?

Comment: there are many ways of killing a process by time, but if _timeout_ is available I don't see why not to use it.

Comment: Nice to see the complexity reduction in this answer. Will upvote with clearer detail on flags used not explained in answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use grep -m 1 to stop after the first match

Comment: -m 1 will stop after the first match in each file searched.

Comment: because I try on some options and its not stop the grep search?

Comment: grep -R -m 1 "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep -wq "param" will still return every file that matches but will move on to the next file when it finds the first match.  This speeds things up a fair bit.  lacopo's answer below will return the first match.

Comment: yes but my quastion was about to match on the first try and stop not to cont to other files how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This way:

grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep -wq "param" | head -n 1

Comment: hi
sorry but this not stop the grep procedure after the first match of param 
Yael

Comment: That's because "grep" doesn't know that "head" has closed the pipe until it tries to write the second match.

Comment: I'm tempted to delete the answer, but I think my mistake is in some way instructing

Comment: Yeah, just leave it. Using pipes+head raises some questions, not all commands have a -m option like grep. See: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/133120-problem-pipes-infinite-streams.html

Comment: ( /path/to/slow command with options ) & sleep 5 ; kill $! 

this not good for me because I check the $? of the grep
what can I to do, seems I have abig problem -:(

Comment: Try this: 

`for i in \`grep -l -s -R param /var/*\`; do grep -m 1 param $i; break;done`

Comment: Check this out to kill grep immediately after first hit: http://superuser.com/a/275962/37154 So, in this case, `head -n 1 <( exec grep -sRw -m1 "linux" /var ); kill $!`. You can wrap this in `()` and grep its output to get the correct RC whether the first `grep` found it or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU grep, try this:

```
  -m, --max-count=NUM       stop after NUM matches
```