# how to execute programs in non-blocking way from scripts

Tags: linux, scripting, nonblocking

I have series of program files, a.out, b.out, c.out

I want to execute them one after the other after certain delay between each program. like
./a.out -input parameters
----wait for 50 sec----
./b.out -input parameters
-----wait for 100 sec----
./c.out

I want to execute b.out 50 seconds after a.out has started execution but in a non-blocking way i.e. I don't want to wait for 50sec after a.out has finished execution.

Can anyone suggest ways of doing this in linux as I'm putting this into a script that will automate tasks for me

Answer (score 11):

You want *background processes*:

```
./a.out -parameters & 
sleep 50 
./b.out -parameters & 
sleep 100 
./c.out &
```

Background processes run without blocking your terminal; you can control them in a limited way with the `jobs` facility.

Answer (score 1):

To run it in background, you can use `a.out &`.

For timeout, consider [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay) .

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Bash script and the *sleep* program:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out -input parameters
sleep 50
./b.out -input parameters
sleep 100
./c.out
```

Comment: that would still be synchronous

Comment: Oops, that's right. Kilian's answer is correct, and should be accepted.