# AWK - how to end this command after 60 seconds?

Tags: awk, system

I have this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {system ("mplayer mms :// xx.xx.xx -dumpstream -dumpfile xxx.wmv")}'
```

How to end this command after 60 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

Comment: Why are you running that in an AWK `system` command instead of directly? Is it part of a larger AWK script?

Comment: `miku` Thank you for the link.                                  `Dennis Williamson` Yes. This will be part of a larger awk script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the pid of a bash subprocess by querying `$!`. Store the value of the awk process, sleep for 60 seconds and the kill the awk process.

```
awk 'BEGIN {system ("mplayer mms :// xx.xx.xx -dumpstream -dumpfile xxx.wmv")}' &
pid=$!
sleep 60
kill $pid
```

This requires that you run the awk process as a background process `&` so that the parent control continues.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But how to end after 60 seconds to download a file by mplayer?

Comment: If you want to end 60 seconds after the command finishes, leave off the `&`. That way the sleep won't be executed until the command has finished.

Comment: My mistake. I want to download the file only 60 seconds.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want the download to take only 60 seconds (I'm afraid I can't help you with this). Or do you want the download to only proceed for 60 seconds (in which case see my original response).