# How to timeout within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

So this is what I am trying to do -

```
for test in `ls Tests`; do

for file in `ls FileFolder`; do

output=`python devcap $test $file`

echo $test $file $output >>result.txt

done

done
```

How do I timeout the $output if it takes longer than say 5 seconds and move to the next $file?

Can I redirect the stderr to result.txt as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for test in `ls Tests`; do

for file in `ls FileFolder`; do

output=`python devcap $test $file`

sleep 5

echo $test $file $output >>result.txt

done

done
```

Comment: I tried it.Its not working. The code just hangs up the shell and doesn't move forward.

Comment: have you tried to add sleep 5 in your code? btw I updated my answer