# How to exit from a command after n seconds?

Tags: bash, exit

I'm writing a script and would like to know how to ask one of the commands to exit after few seconds. For eg. let's suppose my script runs 2 application commands in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat servers`
do
<command 1> $i >> Output_file  #Consistency command
<command 2> $i >> Output_file  #Communication check
done
```

These commands are to check consistency & communication to/from application. I want to know how do I make sure that command 1 & 2 runs for only few seconds and if there is no response from particular host, move on to next command.

Comment: You seem to be looking for this: [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

Comment: I had a look @ that, isn't there an easier way?? I don't want to make my tiny script too complex! :)

Comment: this is useful for imagemagick's `display` command which doesn't play nicely with xargs.

Answer (score 17):

<strike>bash</strike> coreutils has got 'timeout` command.

From manual:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be "s" for seconds (the default), "m" for
>   minutes, "h" for hours or "d" for days.

for example:

`timeout 5 sleep 6`

Comment: I'm trying for rpcinfo on solaris... "timeout 5 rpcinfo -p server_name" it gives "command not found" , but there is man page entry for it.

Comment: `timeout` isn't a bash built-in.  It's provided by GNU coreutils.

Comment: So how do I use it ??

Comment: @Marcos not sure what you mean? See if you can install `coreutils`. If you can, then you should get `timeout` command.