# Prevent bash script from hanging

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have bash-script with following code:

```
function test() {
  some_code
  ...
  make
  some_code
}

test
some_other_code
```

*test()* could contain any code that might run unreasonably long.

I was trying to use something like:

```
function test() {
  cd $WORK_FOLDER
  make
}

run_timeout()
{
local timeout=$1
$2 &
local pid=$!
while ps $pid >/dev/null && [ $timeout -ne 0 ]; do
  sleep 1
  let timeout--  
done  
kill -9 $pid 2>/dev/null && echo "Process $pid killed because executed too long"
}

run_timeout 15 "test"
run_timeout 5 "test"
```

But *make* was still running after the estimated time.

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Is there any technique that prevents a bash script from hanging?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use `test` as a function command since it's a built in *nix command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes

Comment: You probably want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Note that you are expected to use full words rather than 'SMS-ese' abbreviations (so 'something', not 'smth').  Generally, it is not a good idea to jump straight to `kill -9`; use `kill -15` (aka `TERM`), and `kill -1` (aka HUP) before resorting to `kill -9` (aka KILL).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the $2 & is where you run the long function right? I had the same problem and some time, depending on what is in the function you will have multiple process ... I don t know if my solution is the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

change :

```
$2 &
```

for :

```
awk '{system($2)}' &
```

this way, pid =$! will give you the awk pid and by killing the awk, you kill the whole process thing.

Comment: I think this is a prime example of why software packages keep getting slower and slower, requiring processors to get faster and faster, and systems needing more and more memory...