# Timeout a command efficiently and capture output to a variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I need to run a command and kill it when running too long, in a bash script. I also need to capture all output to a variable. If the command finishes first, I need to release/kill the watchdog process (e.g. sleep) because I may run a list of such commands.

Unfortunately the "timeout" command is not available to me, othervise I could do something like this:

```
output=`timeout -s 9 $TIMEOUT my-command`
```

and check for the exit code 124 to see if there was a timeout.

Therefore my solution of choice is [by @Dmitry to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay):

```
( my_command ) & pid=$!
( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
```

Unfortunately the following does not capture anything to the $output:

```
( output=`my_command` ) & pid=$!
```

I could dump the output to a file and then load it in the variable like this, but I'd rather do without files:

```
( `my_command >$outfile` ) & pid=$!
...
output=`cat $outfile`
rm -f $outfile
```

My question: is there a better way? Ideally capturing the stderr as well to another variable without using files?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the `$()` notation allows for multiple commands, so you can do this:

```
output=$(
    ( my_command ) & pid=$!
    ( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
    wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
)
```

You can also use regular `()` to group commands and then redirect all their output.  Redirecting stderr to stdout can be done using `2>&1`, so you end up with this:

```
output=$(
    (
        ( my_command ) & pid=$!
        ( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
        wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
    ) 2>&1
)
```

Comment: Grouping is done with curly brackets `{...}`, not parentheses.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: curly braces may work as well, but parentheses do work.

Comment: Parentheses are for _subshells_. Please see the [_Grouping Commands_ section in the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Cool, I didn't know that. I thought they were the same with the only difference that we had to place a `;` before end squiggly bracket. Good stuff.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: A subshell seems appropriate in this case since there's no need to keep the variables that were used for implementing the timeout functionality.  Some may argue it is less efficient to use a subshell, but that's another issue.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Using () captures the output, but exits only when the timeout expires - too long for my_command that finishes fast.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: using grouping {} instead of braces gives a bad substitution error.

Comment: @elomage You misunderstood where I'm talking about curly brackets. It's not for `$(...)`. It's for the one inside: `output=$(my_command & pid=$!; { sleep ...... ; } > 2>&1 )`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, {} work inside, but the long execution for short commands still remains. If I do not place my_command and sleep in separate subshells, sleep needs to finish before wait && pkill could kill it from the script.

Comment: @elomage: That's strange.  I tried it and if the command finishes before the timeout, I get the output as soon as the command finishes.  The logic of the `wait` and `pkill` is supposed to kill the sleep command if the command finishes before the timeout.

Comment: +1 reasonable solution, for moving the conversation forward  (debugging the issue), and for sticking with it. Good luck to all.