# timeout --> command not found in linux server

Tags: linux, command, cpanel

I am using linux server from cPanel. Now I need to use one of the linux command to run. And the command is 'timeout'. My command is something as below

```
$timeout 2s ./myexecutable < input > output
```

This is just running ok in my linux machine. But I want to run it in server(linux). But it is not running out there. I saw error log using `2>$1` . and it says command not found.

So how do I specify the path. That means how can I know the exact path to run it.

I am very new to this type of server stuff, so please don't be rude :D.. whatever you know please help me to get out of it.
thank you

Comment: The `timeout` command is probably not installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay for some options on where to get it. If you know for sure it's installed but not where it is, try the `locate` command (`locate timeout`). Otherwise ask your server operator.

Comment: how to run locate command in linux server @DavidNorris

Comment: Do you control the server, ie have root access and/or shell access?  Or is it a commercial server? If so, which one?  If you have shell access, indicate results of `ls /usr/bin/locate` and `ls /usr/bin/timeout`.  If no shell access, what do you have?

Answer (score 7):

On Mac, you can use gtimeout from the coreutils package. To install it, run

```
brew install coreutils
```

If you need the command to be called "timeout" then you can alias it.

```
alias timeout="gtimeout"
```