# set max time a docker container can be open

Tags: python, bash, containers, docker

I'm opening a docker container and running an inline bash script. The bash script runs python code but I'm not always sure what that code will be.

Because it's arbitrary code, I'd like to enable a kill switch to close this container within 30 seconds. Is there a way to do that within this code that I'm running:

```
docker run my/image sh -c '$(curl -ss -o python_file.py https://www.example.com); \
    python python_file.py'
```

Basically before running the python file, I'd like to start a timer. And if that timer hits 30 seconds, I run docker kill this specific container.

I've tried the following but it's not working.

```
timeout 30 docker run my/image sh -c '$(curl -ss -o python_file.py https://www.example.com); \
    python python_file.py'
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)?

Comment: I saw those. I'm pretty crap at bash so I wasn't able to figure out how to get it working into that the bash string.

Comment: i tried using something like timeout 30 docker run...  but didn't work.

Comment: looks like doing timeout right before running the python script works. but not before opening a docker container.

Comment: I haven't messed with docker, but if you want to use `timeout`, try putting the whole thing (`docker ...`) in a script and then running `timeout 30 script` after making it executable.

Comment: timeout is working now...but that's just my case cause i'm only running one script in it that i want to timeout. thanks!

Comment: No problem, also not really sure why `$(curl -ss ...);`  instead of just `curl -ss ...;`, but glad it's working.