# Bash Script Terminate a command and continue

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command, terminate

I have a script that after a while executes a command that cannot stop unless you terminate it. How do I stop the command and continue my script?

Let's say I run `apt-get update` and I want to stop it in a N period of time and then continue my script.

Comment: Can you show your script in question?

Comment: Did you look at the `timeout` command?

Comment: echo  -e "Enter monitor card id: \c "
read  monitorcard
echo  "Monitor id is: $monitorcard "
echo  "Starting Scan For Wps "
eval  'wash -i $monitorcard '

No i haven't yey.. but i will

Comment: have a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a sh script that make use of the "timeout" command to:

Run "sleep 30", timeout on 10 seconds, then kill "TERM", wait 3s, then kill -9

```
TIMEOUT_TO_SIGNAL=10
SIGNAL_AFTER_TIMEOUT=TERM
WAIT_FOR_KILL="3s"
COMMAND_TO_EXEC="sleep 30"

echo "Run \"$COMMAND_TO_EXEC\", timeout on $TIMEOUT_TO_SIGNAL seconds, then kill \"$SIGNAL_AFTER_TIMEOUT\", wait $WAIT_FOR_KILL, then kill -9"
timeout --signal=$SIGNAL_AFTER_TIMEOUT --kill-after=$WAIT_FOR_KILL $TIMEOUT_TO_SIGNAL $COMMAND_TO_EXEC

if [ $? -eq 124 ]
then
    echo "The command $COMMAND_TO_EXEC timed out"
else
    echo "The command $COMMAND_TO_EXEC executed without timeout"
fi
```