# Script in bash to wait on the process and then give up

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have script which I assuming hangs sometimes.

My goal is wait till the script got completed or kill it if it didn't come up after 30 sec with some return code.

```
(function) & pid=$!
 wait $pid || sleep 30 || kill -9 $pid
 finished=$?
```

So I am thinking of above. I don't want to waste extra second sleeping if process finishes early that why I am using wait.

Is this correct or any better approach ?

Comment: This has been answered multiple times - here is how to do a timeout in bash: http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3

Answer (score 2):

There is a better approach: use the `timeout` command.

See [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay) for more details.