# send control c to a linux command after specific time intervel?

Tags: linux, shell

Shell Scripting:

I am doing some testing on my router, I am using mdk3 and reaver utility for that.

here are the two commands:

```
[cmd1]  echo y|reaver -i wlan2mon -b 00:FF:EE:CC:DS:B6 -vv    -l 230
[cmd2]  sudo mdk3 wlan2mon a -a 00:FF:EE:CC:DS:B6
```

goal:

I am trying to create a shell script which will run [cmd1] for 2 minutes, then it will send the ctrl + c signal to [cmd1] so that it will save the reaver session.

then cmd2 will run for 2 minutes and this will also stop after that.

these two will be in loop.

below is the sample script which I written can you add timer to it..?

```
    #!/bin/bash

while :; do echo
echo "running mdk for 2 minutes";
timeout 120 sudo mdk3 wlan2mon a -a 00:FF:EE:CC:DS:B6;

echo "mdk finished";
echo "starting reaver for 2 minutes ";

#here timeout won't work, as ctrl+c can only save the state.

//add code here to run reaver utility for two minutes and send ctrl+c to it
echo y|reaver -i wlan2mon -b 00:FF:EE:CC:DS:B6 -vv;
 echo "reaver ran for two minutes";



done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

Comment: `sleep 120; killall -INT reaver` ?

Comment: can you explain @jamieguinan

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with the `reaver` program, but I think the following should work,

```
# Run reaver as a background process (add &)
echo y|reaver -i wlan2mon -b 00:FF:EE:CC:DS:B6 -vv &
# Save the process id.
reaverpid=$!
# Sleep 2 minutes
sleep 120
# Send SIGINT, which is what ctrl-c normally does.
kill -SIGINT $reaverpid
```