# How to stop a gitlab multi runner script that runs infinitely?

Tags: java, bash, jar, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Suppose I run a jar in Gitlab CI to check if it fails or runs.

```
script:
 - java -jar someJar.jar
More Tasks below
```

This runs a java application which runs infinitely by nature. I need to stop this application programmatically equivalent to `Ctrl + C` or some bash timeout.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: How about wrapping it with something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay

Comment: Yes that would work really well, let me check