# How to repeatedly start and kill a never ending bash process

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How do I repeatedly start and kill a bash script that takes a long time. I have a analyze_realtime.sh that runs indefinitely, but I only want to run it for X second bursts (just say 15s for now).

`while true; do analyze_realtime.sh; sleep 15; done`

The problem with this is that analyze_realtime.sh never finishes, so this logic doesn't work. Is there a way to kill the process after 15 seconds, then start it again?

I was thinking something with `analyze_realtime.sh&`, `ps`, and `kill` may work. Is there anything simpler?

Answer (score 3):

### Try this out

```
while true; do
    analyze_realtime.sh & # put script execution in background
    sleep 15
    kill %1
done
```

### Explanation

`%1` refer to the latest process ran in background

Answer (score 3):

```
 while true;
 do
   analyze_realtime.sh &
   jobpid=$! # This gets the pid of the bg job
   sleep 15
   kill $jobpid
   if ps -p $jobpid &>/dev/null; then
     echo "$jobpid didn't get killed. Moving on..." 
   fi
 done
```

You can do more under the `if-statement`, sending other SIGNALs if `SIGHUP` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timeout` utility from `coreutils`:

```
while true; do
    timeout 15 analyze_realtime.sh
done
```

(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581821/8868289))