# Writing graceful timeout for Nagios plugin

Tags: monitoring, nagios

From [Nagios' Plugin Development Guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#RUNTIME):

> Plugins have a very limited runtime - typically 10 sec. As a result, it is very important for plugins to maintain internal code to exit if runtime exceeds a threshold.
>
> All plugins should timeout gracefully, not just networking plugins.

How can I implement a timeout mechanism into my custom plugin? Basically I want my plugin to return a status code 3 - UNKNOWN instead of the default 1 - CRITICAL when the plugin times out, to reduce the number of false positives generated.

**EDIT:** My plugin is written in Bash.

Comment: There seem to be many suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay/687994#687994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timeout`. Here is example usage:

```
timeout 15 ping google.com
if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
    echo "UNKNOWN - Time limit exceeded."
    exit 3
if
```

You will get return exit status 124 from `timeout` when your command don't finish in defined time - `15` sec.