# Timeout a command in batch without unnecessary delay

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timeout, long-running-processes, taskkill

> I am essentially looking for this solution '[timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)', but it must be for a `script.bat` file.

Given a `cmd.exe` terminal.
And we `start "long-running" /path/to/long-running` program.
And we set a `timeout /t 600 /nobreak` to give the program time to run.
After which we `taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq long-running"` to stop the program.

When the program ends earlier than 600s, say after 120s.

Then the script must terminate early without waiting for the timeout to reach 600s.

**How can we terminate the script at the earlier of the two? [ timeout elapsed / early termination ]**

Comment: You would not be able to use the `TIMEOUT` command. You would need to create a loop to keep checking every few seconds if the program is running and/or if the timeout value has been reached.

Comment: If all your doing is waiting for the program to close, what's wrong with `start /wait ...`

Comment: Think of a server that runs as a daemon but you have a memory leak in and restarting it every x seconds is acceptable. However, it might crash for any other reason as well. How do you know when to restart the server? Polling as @Squashman suggested is likely the only solution I can see.