# In what order should I send signals to gracefully shutdown processes?

Tags: bash, signals, job-control, sigterm

In a [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782/how-do-i-limit-the-running-time-of-a-bash-script#comment340090_526815) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782#526815) of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782), the commenter says:

> don’t use kill -9 unless absolutely
>   necessary! SIGKILL can’t be trapped so
>   the killed program can’t run any
>   shutdown routines to e.g. erase
>   temporary files. First try HUP (1),
>   then INT (2), then QUIT (3)

I agree in principle about `SIGKILL`, but the rest is news to me. Given that the default signal sent by `kill` is `SIGTERM`, I would expect it is the most-commonly expected signal for graceful shutdown of an arbitrary process. Also, I have seen `SIGHUP` used for non-terminating reasons, such as telling a daemon "re-read your config file." And it seems to me that `SIGINT` (the same interrupt you'd typically get with Ctrl-C, right?) isn't as widely supported as it ought to be, or terminates rather ungracefully.

Given that `SIGKILL` is a last resort — **Which signals, and in what order**, should you send to an arbitrary process, in order to shut it down as gracefully as possible?

Please substantiate your answers with supporting facts (beyond personal preference or opinion) or references, if you can.

Note: I am particularly interested in best practices that include consideration of bash/Cygwin.

**Edit:** So far, nobody seems to mention INT or QUIT, and there's limited mention of HUP. Is there any reason to include these in an orderly process-killing?

Comment: If you have to resort to SIGKILL to really kill a process, I would consider it a bug in the program.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**SIGTERM tells an application to terminate.**  The other signals tell the application other things which are unrelated to shutdown but may sometimes have the same result.  Don't use those.  If you want an application to shut down, tell it to.  Don't give it misleading signals.

Some people believe the smart standard way of terminating a process is by sending it a slew of signals, such as HUP, INT, TERM and finally KILL.  This is ridiculous.  The right signal for termination is SIGTERM and if SIGTERM doesn't terminate the process instantly, as you might prefer, it's because the application has chosen to handle the signal.  Which means it has a very good reason to not terminate immediately:  It's got cleanup work to do.  If you interrupt that cleanup work with other signals, there's no telling what data from memory it hasn't yet saved to disk, what client applications are left hanging or whether you're interrupting it "mid-sentence" which is effectively data corruption.

For more information on what the real meaning of the signals is, see sigaction(2).  Don't confuse "Default Action" with "Description", they are not the same thing.

`SIGINT` is used to signal an interactive "keyboard interrupt" of the process.  Some programs may handle the situation in a special way for the purpose of terminal users.

`SIGHUP` is used to signal that the terminal has disappeared and is no longer looking at the process.  That is all.  Some processes choose to shut down in response, generally because their operation makes no sense without a terminal, some choose to do other things such as recheck configuration files.

`SIGKILL` is used to forcefully remove the process from the kernel.  It is special in the sense that it's not actually a signal to the process but rather gets interpreted by the kernel directly.

**Don't send SIGKILL.** - `SIGKILL` should certainly never be sent by scripts.  If the application handles the `SIGTERM`, it can take it a second to cleanup, it can take a minute, **it can take an hour**.  Depending on what the application has to get done before it's ready to end.  Any logic that "*assumes*" an application's cleanup sequence has taken long enough and needs to be shortcut or SIGKILLed after X seconds is **just plain wrong**.

The only reason why an application would *need* a `SIGKILL` to terminate, is if something bugged out during its cleanup sequence.  In which case you can open a terminal and `SIGKILL` it manually.  Aside from that, the only one other reason why you'd `SIGKILL` something is because you *WANT* to prevent it from cleaning itself up.

Even though half the world blindly sends `SIGKILL` after 5 seconds it's still horribly wrong thing to do.

Comment: You're right that there's a lot of misuse of SIGKILL out there. But there is a time and place to use it, even from a script. Many, many apps trap SIGTERM and exit gracefully in less than a second or within just a few seconds, and one of those is still running 30 secs later it's because it's wedged.

Comment: @dwc: Try letting it run once for an hour.  If it doesn't die then it's "wedged" and either fix it, or be lazy and in the future SIGKILL it after some time.  *Take note* that you're probably corrupting stuff and remember that this is NOT something you should be doing "by default".

Comment: @lhunath: Hope you don't mind, I rearranged your paragraphs in order to make the answer more directly and clearly follow from the question. The anti-SIGKILL rant is good stuff, but a secondary point. Thanks again for an excellent & educational answer.

Comment: *Don't send SIGKILL. Ever. Just plain wrong.* Really? Even if your system is already burning thanks to infinite loops. Good luck. -1

Comment: The only time I care to signal a program to stop is when it's not responding, so I'd gladly send SIGKILL before anything else, and I don't care what it does with its data since I'm going to restart it anyway. There's a lot of bugs out there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 29):

**Short Answer**: Send `SIGTERM`, 30 seconds later, `SIGKILL`. That is, send `SIGTERM`, wait a bit (it may vary from program to program, you may know your system better, but 5 to 30 seconds is enough. When shutting down a machine, you may see it automatically waiting up to 1'30s. Why the hurry, after all?), then send `SIGKILL`.

**Reasonable Answer**: `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGKILL`
This is more than enough. The process will **very** probably terminate before `SIGKILL`.

**Long Answer**: `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGKILL`

This is unnecessary, but at least you are not misleading the process regarding your message. All these signals *do* mean you want the process to stop what it is doing and exit.

No matter what answer you choose from this explanation, keep that in mind!

If you send a signal that means something else, the process may handle it in very different ways (on one hand). On the other hand, if the process doesn't handle the signal, it doesn't matter what you send after all, the process will quit anyway (when the default action is to terminate, of course).

So, you must think as yourself as a programmer. Would you code a function handler for, lets say, `SIGHUP` to quit a program that connects with something, or would you loop it to try to connect again? That is the main question here! That is why it is important to just send signals that mean what you intend.

**Almost Stupid Long Answer**:

The table bellow contains the relevant signals, and the default actions in case the program does not handle them.

I ordered them in the order I suggest to use (BTW, I suggest you to use the *reasonable answer*, not this one here), if you really need to try them all (it would be fun to say the table is ordered in terms of the destruction they may cause, but that is not *completely* true).

The signals with an asterisk (*) are **NOT** recommended. The important thing about these is that you may never know what it is programmed to do. Specially `SIGUSR`! It may start the apocalipse (it is a free signal for a programmer do whatever he/she wants!). But, if not handled **OR** in the unlikely case it is handled to terminate, the program will terminate.

In the table, the signals with default options to terminate and generate a core dump are left in the end, just before `SIGKILL`.

```
Signal     Value     Action   Comment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
SIGINT        2       Term    Famous CONTROL+C interrupt from keyboard
SIGHUP        1       Term    Disconnected terminal or parent died
SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe
SIGALRM(*)   14       Term    Timer signal from alarm
SIGUSR2(*)   12       Term    User-defined signal 2
SIGUSR1(*)   10       Term    User-defined signal 1
SIGQUIT       3       Core    CONTRL+\ or quit from keyboard
SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
```

Then I would suggest for this *almost stupid long answer*: 
`SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGPIPE`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGKILL`

And finally, the

**Definitely Stupid Long Long Answer**:

Don't try this at home.

`SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGPIPE`, `SIGALRM`, `SIGUSR2`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE` and if nothing worked, `SIGKILL`.

`SIGUSR2` should be tried before `SIGUSR1` because we are better off if the program doesn't handle the signal. And it is much more likely for it to handle `SIGUSR1` if it handles just one of them.

**BTW, the KILL**: it is not wrong to send `SIGKILL` to a process, as other answer stated. Well, think what happens when you send a `shutdown` command? It will try `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` only. Why do you think that is the case? And why do you need any other signals, if the very `shutdown` command uses only these two?

---

Now, back to the **long answer**, this is a nice oneliner:

```
for SIG in 15 2 3 6 9 ; do echo $SIG ; echo kill -$SIG $PID || break ; sleep 30 ; done
```

It sleeps for 30 seconds between signals. Why else would you need a *oneliner*? ;)

Also, recommended: try it with only signals `15 2 9` from the **reasonable answer**.

*safety*: remove the second `echo` when you are ready to go. I call it my `dry-run` for *onliners*. Always use it to test.

---

**Script killgracefully**

Actually I was so intrigued by this question that I decided to create a small script to do just that. Please, feel free to download (clone) it here:

GitHub link to [Killgracefully repository](https://github.com/drbeco/killgracefully)

Comment: I've always wondered why the default action for `SIGUSRx` is to terminate. If a program sends that signal, it's because it wants the target to do something specific. If the target isn't actually programmed to do anything when it receives that signal, then sure, it's not going to be able to do what the process that sent the signal intends, but how does that imply it's desirable for the process to immediately terminate? That's kind of like designing an OS to immediately shut down the computer if it receives data from a USB device it doesn't have a driver for.

Comment: Why would you ever send a SIGPIPE if is not a pipe, like suggested in the "almost stupid long answer"?

Comment: As I'm sure you read it carefully already, it is NOT recommended, but it is there to show a list of possible orders only. But again, not recommended.

Answer (score 8):

Typically you'd send `SIGTERM`, the default of kill. It's the default for a reason. Only if a program does not shutdown in a reasonable amount of time should you resort to `SIGKILL`. But note that with `SIGKILL` the program has no possibility to clean things up und data could be corrupted.

As for `SIGHUP`, `HUP` stands for "hang up" and historically meant that the modem disconnected. It's essentially equivalent to `SIGTERM`. The reason that daemons sometimes use `SIGHUP` to restart or reload config is that daemons detach from any controlling terminals as a daemon doesn't need those and therefore would never receive `SIGHUP`, so that signal was considered as "freed up" for general use. Not all daemons use this for reload! The default action for SIGHUP is to terminate and many daemons behave that way! So you can't go blindly sending `SIGHUP`s to daemons and expecting them to survive.

**Edit:** `SIGINT` is probably inappropriate to terminate a process, as it's normally tied to `^C` or whatever the terminal setting is to interrupt a program. Many programs capture this for their own purposes, so it's common enough for it not to work. `SIGQUIT` typically has the default of creating a core dump, and unless you want core files laying around it's not a good candidate, either.

Summary: if you send `SIGTERM` and the program doesn't die within your timeframe then send it `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Note that following it up with SIGKILL should only be done in situations where shutting down instantly is a higher priority than preventing data loss/data corruption.

Comment: @dwc I did not understand the following point in your answer. could you please help             "The reason that daemons sometimes use SIGHUP to restart or reload config is that daemons detach from any controlling terminals and therefore would never receive SIGTERM, so that signal was considered as "freed up" for general use."

Comment: @Jack Let me try: SIGHUP is the "hang up" signal which tells a process that the terminal got disconnected. Since daemons run in the background, they don't need terminals. That means that a "hang up" signal isn't relevant to daemons. They'll never receive it from a terminal disconnection, since they don't have terminals connected in the first place. And since the signal is defined anyway, though they don't need it for the original purpose, many daemons use it instead for a different purpose, such as re-reading their config files.

Comment: Re: "SIGINT is probably in appropriate", I have a process (not mine, closed source, etc) which consistently will not respond to SIGTERM, but responds to SIGINT. I chose to use SIGINT in my script, because it seemed safer than resorting to SIGKILL. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy these signals are merely conventions, if it doesn't respond appropriately to SIGTERM then you should choose a signal that it does respond to

Answer (score 7):

**`SIGTERM`** actually means sending an application a message: "*would you be so kind and commit suicide*". It can be trapped and handled by application to run cleanup and shutdown code.

**`SIGKILL`** cannot be trapped by application. Application gets killed by OS without any chance for cleanup.

It's typical to send `SIGTERM` first, sleep some time, then send `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I suppose polling would be a bit more efficient than sleeping (before the SIGKILL)

Comment: @OhadSchneider it would, but that would require something more than simple bash command.

Comment: Yeah I guess you would need to loop while the process is still alive using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15774758/67824.

Answer (score 4):

- SIGTERM is equivalent to "clicking the 'X' " in a window.
- SIGTERM is what Linux uses first, when it is shutting down.

Comment: *"SIGTERM is equivalent to "clicking the 'X' " in a window"* No, it is not, because any one application can easily open any number of (document and tool, for example) windows, let alone dialogs, and it may not even respond to a last window close command as it does to an exit command (I can't think of any obvious examples, but while non-obvious, there's no reason why it can't be done that way). SIGTERM is (or should be) equivalent to gracefully asking the application to terminate, *however that might be performed in that particular application*.

Answer (score 4):

With all the discussion going on here, no code has been offered. Here's my take:

```
#!/bin/bash

$pid = 1234

echo "Killing process $pid..."
kill $pid

waitAttempts=30 
for i in $(seq 1 $waitAttempts)
do
    echo "Checking if process is alive (attempt #$i / $waitAttempts)..."
    sleep 1

    if ps -p $pid > /dev/null
    then
        echo "Process $pid is still running"
    else
        echo "Process $pid has shut down successfully"
        break
    fi
done

if ps -p $pid > /dev/null
then
    echo "Could not shut down process $pid gracefully - killing it forcibly..."
    kill -SIGKILL $pid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

HUP sounds like rubbish to me. I'd send it to get a daemon to re-read its configuration.

SIGTERM can be intercepted; your daemons just might have clean-up code to run when it receives that signal. You cannot do that for SIGKILL. Thus with SIGKILL you are not giving the daemon's author any options.

More on that on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(Unix))