# Bash hide "killed"

Tags: bash, redirect, kill

I cannot see to hide the "killed" output from my script. Please help.

```
killall -9 $SCRIPT
```

I have tried:

```
killall -9 $SCRIPT >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and everyone redirect combination it seems. Thanks for the help.

*** UPDATE ***

The main script cannot run in the background. It outputs a bunch on information to the user while running. Thanks for the input though. Any other ideas?

Here is the desired output

HEV Terminated
administrator@HEV-DEV:~/hev-1.2.7$

Here is the current output:

HEV Terminated
Killed
administrator@HEV-DEV:~/hev-1.2.7$

Comment: please edit your question to include a sample of the "killed" output you hope to avoid. Good luck.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash

Comment: Don't use `-9`. It should not be necessary, and if it is, then `$SCRIPT` has a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Also, see questions [8074904 (How to shield the kill output)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074904/how-to-shield-the-kill-output) and [714855 (Suppress Notice of Forked Command Being Killed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714855/suppress-notice-of-forked-command-being-killed).

Answer (score 4):

It's not the script printing it, it's the shell. You can suppress it by putting it in the background and waiting for it to finish, redirecting the error from there:

```
./script &
wait 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: The main script cannot run in the background

Comment: Can you kill it with SIGINT?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be avoided if you execute the script (including the `&`) in a subshell:

```
$ ( ./script.sh & )
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14208 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
16134 pts/0    00:00:00 script.sh
16135 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep
16136 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
$ killall script.sh
$
```

If I execute it (without the subshell) like `./script.sh` then I get the output

```
[1]+  Terminated              ./script.sh &>/dev/null
```

Comment: The main script cannot run in the background

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
(killall -9 $SCRIPT) 2>/dev/null
```

This executes the "killall" in a subshell and all output from that subshell is redirected, including the the "KILLED" output.

Answer (score 0):

Try killall -q,--quiet          don't print complaints

```bash
killall -q -9 $SCRIPT
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer, and how it is different from the other 3 answers on this 7 year old question.