# How to find processes based on port and kill them all?

Tags: bash, shell

Find processes based on port number and kill them all.

```
ps -efl | grep PORT_NUMBER | kill -9 process_found_previously
```

how to complete the last column?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The problem with `ps -efl | grep PORT_NUMBER` is that `PORT_NUMBER` may match other columns in the output of `ps` as well (date, time, pid, ...). A potential killing spree if run by root!

I would do this instead :

```
PORT_NUMBER=1234
lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER} | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Breakdown of command

- (`lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER}`) -- list all processes that is listening on that tcp port
- (`awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}'`) -- ignore first line, print second column of each line
- (`xargs kill`) -- pass on the results as an argument to `kill`. There may be several.

Comment: Fuser (below) is simpler

Comment: This is great. Got a lovely little alias now:

`killport() {
  lsof -i tcp:$1 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
}`

killing off by port is now simply a case of writing e.g.: `killport 3984`

Comment: Look at DanS's answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12295745/67824). You can do without the `awk` if you use the `-it` option that was intended exactly for that: *-t       specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output may be  piped  to  kill(1).*. Needless to say, that would be a better and more reliable approach.

Comment: can someone please provide a stunt we can use when we have more than one port involved, for example when nginx is running 100 processes on many ports. Thanks.

Comment: just an addition:  ```A=1234; B=4567; lsof -i tcp:${A} -i tcp:${B} -t | xargs kill ```

Comment: -n make lsof faster, uniq kill only once per process: lsof -n -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER} | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' |uniq | xargs kill

Comment: Not works for websocket ports, instead this works `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:1234)`

Comment: The `kill` isn't really killing that process in my case, I have to use `kill -9`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it works great when executed from the terminal. But sadly enough, when i execute this from a script (.sh file) it won't work (and won't issue any error), as the process won't be killed.

Answer (score 32):

1.) `lsof -w -n -i tcp:8080`

2.) `kill -9 processId`

Comment: Said many times here, don't use `kill -9`, just try `kill` or use `kill -15` what does SIGTERM and if doesn't work force it with `kill -9` finally.

Answer (score 30):

```
kill $( lsof -i:6000 -t )
```

Or if you need permissions:

```
sudo kill $( sudo lsof -i:6000 -t )
```

Comment: This will work in most cases, but it seems like there are edge cases where multiple processes can listen on the same port, where the above will fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port.

Comment: i had nginx running multiple processes on the same port.

Comment: (+1) for great answer there. I was wondering how could I add a test condition before it. I mean, I would like to first check if the port is actually being used by a process. So, the script would be something like : `test <check if the port 6000 is being used> && kill $( lsof -i:6000 -t )`.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 20):

Propose to use fuser command:

```
fuser -k -TERM -n tcp ${PORT_NUMBER}
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer. Why bother piping commands when you can simply use an existing utility?

Comment: This fuser command doesn't work in Mac OS X, but Shawn's lsof command does :)

Comment: The actual command for me was: `fuser -k -TERM ${PORT}/tcp` see @Cryptopat [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870808/4524445) below

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

An easy one to remember.

This syntax is probably much more recent than the date of the question!

Answer (score 5):

```
... | awk '{ print $4 }' | xargs kill -9
```

please test with "echo" instead of "kill" before running

Comment: Please, no `kill -9` http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter

Comment: @NathanKidd that link is in german >_>

Comment: @NathanKidd that link is dead but here's an SO discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes.

Answer (score 2):

To kill all processes listening on a particular port, e.g. port 8864

```
kill -9 $ \`lsof -i:8864 -t\`
```

Replace 8864 by the port you want.