# Start a command, count lines of output after 10 seconds, then either restart it or let it run

Tags: linux, bash

I have an interesting situation I am trying to script. I have a program that outputs 26,000 lines after 10 seconds when it starts successfully. Otherwise I have to kill it and start it again. I tried doing something like this:

```
test $(./long_program | wc -l) -eq 26000 && echo "Started successfully"
```

but that only works if the program finishes running. Is there a clever way to watch the output stream of a command and make decisions accordingly? I'm at a loss, not quite sure even how to start searching for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
./long_program > mylogfile &
pid=$!
sleep 10

# then test on mylogfile length and kill $pid if needed
```

Comment: That's actually really simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
until [ $count -eq 26000 ]; do
    killall ./longrun
    #start in background
    ./longrun >output.$$ &
    sleep 10
    count=$(wc -l output.$$ |awk '{print $1}')   
done
echo "done"
#disown so it continues after current login quits
disown -h
```

Comment: Wow never knew about disown. I will be using that for sure.

Comment: [Don't use kill -9](http://stackoverflow.com/a/690631/347411), also kill does not read stdin, so that pipline won't work. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Comment: i replaced it with killall to keep it simple

Comment: Still better to kill by pid, if you would ever want to run multiple instances.