# bash & linux symbols, Jboss

Tags: bash, jboss, signals

I'm writing a script to start Jboss, load an application, send requests to the application, shutdown jboss and repeat. However I dont know how to shut Jboss down from the script. At the moment I'm using

```
pkill -9 java
```

But I dont think this is right, because it kills the process, not shut it down. Is there a way to shut it down similar to pressing CTRL-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a simple

```
pkill java
```

From the man page:

> pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each
>   process

`SIGTERM` will send a termination signal to the process. If the process is well-written, it will catch this signal and perform an orderly shutdown. If that fails, that's when you can use `SIGKILL` (-9) which is a forceable termination with no chance for the process to catch and perform cleanup.

Comment: This worked, but many thanks to @sputnick for providing useful background reading

Answer (score 0):

Never use `kill -9 <PID>` by default. It breaks things up, like *file descriptors* and such.

Start to run `kill <PID>` alone, default is `-15` signal.

See

```
man 7 signal
```

And [In what order should I send signals to gracefully shutdown processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes/690631#690631)

**NOTE**

- `kill` or `pkill` doesn't change things so much, same signals are trigered

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is:

pkill -f jboss

using pkill java could kill any other processes using java on the box.