# Having trouble with inotifywait, trying to watch a directory for golang changes

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, go, inotify

I'm trying to write a bash script to monitor a directory for changes. If the file is a .go or .html file I would like to kill a specific process and then start it.

This is failing all over the place and I'm not sure why. I tried my best to get this working after scouring a lot of web sites for help but I can't get it.

The ideal solution is that I would run it by passing a directory and a file to run and it would just reload the process when I save a file.

I am running it like so:

*./gowatcher /path/to/my/directory/to/watch foo.go*

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WATCH_DIR=$1
FILENAME=$2

function restart_goserver() {
  if go run $FILENAME
  then
    pkill -9 -f $FILENAME > /dev/null 2>&1
    pkill -9 -f a.out > /dev/null 2>&1
    go run $FILENAME &
    echo "started $FILENAME"
  else
    echo "server restart failed"
  fi
}

cd $WATCH_DIR
restart_goserver

echo "watching directory: $WATCH_DIR"
inotifywait -mrq -e close_write $WATCH_DIR | while read file
do
  if grep -E '^(.*\.go)|(.*\.html)$'
  then
    echo "--------------------"
    restart_goserver
  fi
done
```

Comment: And what makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Because I have been trying to get it to work for most of the afternoon and it does not properly monitor the directory for changes + kill/run the supplied go file.

Answer (score 2):

This line seems wrong :

```
grep -E '^(.*\.go)|(.*\.html)$'
```

Should be :

```
echo "$file" | grep -E '^(.*\.go)|(.*\.html)$'
```

Moreover, **don't use `kill -9` by default !** See [In what order should I send signals to gracefully shutdown processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes)

Comment: I put that in there and it still doesn't work. I also switched to zsh if that could introduce a better solution.