# SIGTERM and SIGKILL

Tags: unix, sigkill, sigterm

I was going through following stackoverflow post

[In what order should I send signals to gracefully shutdown processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes)

and came across following statement. Please help me understand the part I have marked in bold. [found in the answer with 3 votes]

"The reason that daemons sometimes use SIGHUP to restart or reload config is that **daemons detach from any controlling terminals and therefore would never receive SIGTERM**, so that signal was considered as "freed up" for general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they must have meant this:

> The reason that daemons sometimes use SIGHUP to restart or reload config is that daemons detach from any controlling terminals and therefore would never receive **SIGHUP**, so that signal was considered as "freed up" for general use.

That is, **SIGHUP** is a signal that would normally be sent only to a process that has a controlling terminal. Since daemons don't have a controlling terminal, they wouldn't get a SIGHUP for the normal reason. So they redefine it for another purpose.

But I could be misinterpreting the original author of that sentence. I think you did the right thing by asking for clarification in a comment on the original answer. Posting here as a separate question doesn't seem ideal...