# Using killall to terminate bash

Tags: bash, cron, terminate

I must terminate a Python script and 2 bash scripts using crontab.

I needed a command to terminate all bash scripts ('killall Python' already works for terminating the python script) but when i use 'killall bash' it doesn't works...

Does anyone knows a solution to my problem? Maybe another command, or an especific way to use killall!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under advice of counsel, I'm forbidden from arming you with anything quite so dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command :

```
killall -s SIGHUP bash
```

but you shouldn't do this, you can potentially kill all bash of all users. Instead, I recommend you to use

```
pkill -f script_name.bash
```

and

```
pkill -1 -f script_name.bash
```

if needed.

Comment: thank you very much! When i write that i get an echoe: kill -TERM number, do you know a way to automate this? so i only need to use one command?

Comment: My command is not `kill` but `killall` like in your own question.

Comment: See my edited post with a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Bash traps many signals like SIGTERM(15) and SIGQUIT(3). You could send SIGHUP(1) or SIGKILL(9):

```
killall -s SIGHUP bash   ## or killall -s 1 bash
killall -s SIGKILL bash  ## or killall -s 9 bash
```

Comment: Nobody should use `kill -9` without a good reason. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/690631/347411 and the 1st command is already given.

Comment: [Don't use `kill -9`!](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#kill)

Comment: Killing a stopped bash doesn't work with SIGHUP. And probably some other conditions too. You could avoid telling such kinds of information but it's too easy to be known sooner.