# Linux short simple command how to send SIGTERM to a process and SIGKILL if it fails to exist in X seconds?

Tags: timeout, kill, kill-process, sigkill, pkill

How should look the Linux command to send terminate signal to the process/PID and if it fails to exit gracefully after 10 seconds kill it?

My attempt is: "sudo timeout -vk 5 10 kill PIDhere" (-v verbose, -k kill after X seconds) but I am not sure if it is good or how to adjust values or if there is better command that even work with part of the name shown in process COMMAND line. ("ps aux" output)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo timeout -vk 5 10 kill PIDhere
```

Will execute `kill`, and then attempt to terminate *that* process if it takes too long. Which shouldn't happen, and presumably isn't what you want (if `kill` was actually hanging, killing it would not affect your actual process). [`timeout`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/timeout) is useful for capping how long a process runs for, not how long it takes to terminate after receiving a signal.

Instead, I'd suggest starting the process asynchronously (e.g. using `&` in a shell, but any language's subprocess library will have similar functionality) and then waiting for the process to terminate after you send it a signal. I describe doing this in Java in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37065167/113632). In the shell that might look like:

```
$ some_process &
# time passes, eventually we decide to terminate the process
$ kill %1
$ sleep 5s
$ kill -s SIGKILL %1 # will fail and do nothing if %1 has already finished
```

Or you could rely on `wait` which will return early if the job terminates before the `sleep` completes:

```
$ some_process &
# time passes
$ kill %1
$ sleep 5s &
$ wait -n %1 %2       # returns once %1 or %2 (sleep) complete
$ kill -s SIGKILL %1  # if %2 completes first %1 is still running and will be killed
```

You can do the same as above with PIDs instead of job IDs, it's just a little more fiddly because you have to worry about PID reuse.

> if there is better command that even work with part of the name

Does [`pkill`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/pkill) do what you want?