# Bash Run command for certain time?

Tags: bash, timeout, command

I am making a bash script for my use. 
How can I run a command for certain time, like 20 seconds and terminate command? 
I tried a lot of solutions but nothing works, I also tried timeout command with no success. Please give me some solution for this.

For example: I want to run this command in script and terminal after 10 sec

```
some command
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout a command in bash without unnecessary delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay)

Comment: I also tried that one but no success.

Comment: There's fourteen answers to that question, including external links. "no success" doesn't mean anything. Please [edit] your question to describe **exactly** what you tried and precisely what doesn't work about it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782/how-do-i-limit-the-running-time-of-a-bash-script/526815#526815

Comment: I added example by editing question

Comment: Also asked in http://superuser.com/questions/593006/bash-run-command-for-certain-time

Answer (score 96):

Here are some bash scripts and a program called timelimit which may solve your problem.
[Kill process after it's been allowed to run for some time](https://superuser.com/questions/153735/kill-process-after-its-been-allowed-to-run-for-some-time)

EDIT: I think I found a better solution. Try using the timeout program. From the man page:
"timeout - run a command with a time limit". For example:

```
timeout 5s sleep 10s
```

It basically runs your command and after the specified duration it will kill it.

Comment: is it available for all Linux distros?

Comment: for example: I want to run this command in script and terminal after 10 sec

'airodump-ng $wlan0'

Comment: @UmairRiaz `timeout` is part of the GNU coreutils package, it should be included in most Linux distributions

Comment: I tried with this command but no success.

Can you give me example with this command?

airodump-ng $wlan0

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would do `timeout 10s airodump-ng $wlan0`. If that's not working then maybe there is something special about your command.

Comment: after this command, I got blank screen when terminal reach to this command.

Comment: Did you disable your wireless interface before you tried running `airodump-ng`? Have you looked at the [documentation](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng) for the program? By the way, I hope you're not breaking into people's Wifi networks...

Answer (score 29):

On systems that do not provide `timeout` command, you can use the following:

```
your-cmd & sleep 30 ; kill $!
```

That will run potentially long running `your-cmd` with timeout of 30 seconds.

If `your-cmd` does not finish within 30 seconds, it will be sent `TERM` signal.

Comment: This is not ideal, because when your-cmd only takes a second, the command still waits for 30 seconds and ending up with an error, because there is no PID to kill anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately the whole issue is more complex.  Right now I use the following (and it is not ideal either):
  timelimit()     # $1 - timeout in seconds
  {
          local t="$1"
          shift
          ( "$@" ) & local pid=$!
          ( sleep "$t" && killtree $pid ) >/dev/null 2>&1 & local wpid=$!
          wait $pid 2>/dev/null
          local rc=$?
          killtree $wpid >/dev/null 2>&1
          return $rc
  }

Comment: That's neat, I like it !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest 2 options:

- On systems where you have the `timeout` command, you can use it according to `man timeout`.
- On systems without it (e.g. CentOS 5), you can use the script supplied with bash `/usr/share/doc/bash-3.2/scripts/timeout`. Use it according to its usage information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to schedule the execution of the script? Then [cron](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial) is your friend.

Answer (score -8):

Use **sleep** and **&&** operand:

**sleep** [time in seconds] && **your-command**

#### Example:

**sleep** 7 && **echo** 'Hello world!'