# How to timeout a group of commands in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command, timeout

I am fiddling with Linux command "timeout": it simply stops a long running command after a given seconds. But I would like to timeout not only a command, but a group of commands. I can group command in two way ( ) and { ;} however none of the following works:

```
timeout 1 { sleep 2; echo something; }
timeout 1 ( sleep 2; echo something )
```

How can I do that with grouping?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`timeout` is not a shell utility and it does not do shell-style processing.  It must be given one single command to execute.  That command, though, can have any number of arguments.  Fortunately, one of the commands that you can give it is `bash`:

```
timeout 1 bash -c '{ sleep 2; echo something; }'
```

Of course, in this form, the braces are now superfluous:

```
timeout 1 bash -c 'sleep 2; echo something'
```

Here, `bash` is the command that `timeout` executes.  `-c` and `sleep 2; echo something` are argument to that command.

Comment: `* * * * * timeout -s9 2h bash -c 'php Cron.file.php my_argument'` (whew...none of the `crontab timeout` articles mentioned that `timeout` only takes one argument, or *maybe they did but i wasn't listening*).

Comment: If you call a local _func()_ in the commands, it will fail with **command not found** - unless you've already exported it with `export -f func` (or `set -o allexport` for all functions in advance).

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the [Here Document EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Here_document&section=2#Unix_shells) method to create the multi-line script on the fly.
The main advantage of it, is that you can **use double quotes without escaping** it:

```
timeout 1s bash <<EOF
    sleep 2s
    echo "something without escaping double quotes"  
EOF
```

Notes:

1. The EOF closure must not follow spaces/tabs, but be at the start of the last line.
2. Make sure you've exported local functions with `export -f my_func` or `set -o allexport` for all functions (before declaring them). **This is relevant for previous answers** as well, since calling bash/sh run the process in new session, unaware to local environment functions.

Answer (score 7):

```
timeout 1 sh -c "sleep 2; echo something"
```