# Using awk with gedit external tools

Tags: macos, awk, gedit

I have used `gedit` with Ubuntu a lot and now transitioning on Macos. I noticed that some of the plugins in the Macos version are missing. For instance, there is no (AFAIK) an out-of-the-box option to comment/uncomment code. However, there is the possibility to define an external tool to basically have whatever you want.

I want to just comment the text selection in R/python style (prepending a `#` before each line of the input). I went to Tools -> Manage External Tools and defined a "Comment Code" tool in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{print "#" $0}'
```

and set Input as "Current Selection" and output as "Replace Current Selection".

It works if you select a text; however if you don't select anything, it stalls forever, since (for what I understood) `awk` is waiting for an input.

How can I avoid this problem? Of course I don't need a `awk` (or whatever) solution, whatever works is fine. I'm not much expert of `bash` tools like `awk` or `sed`, so very likely I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: There isn't any elegant way in Bash to check whether a script is receiving anything on standard input. You could simply add a `timeout` but how exactly to do that is somewhat platform-dependent. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526782/how-do-i-limit-the-running-time-of-a-bash-script

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Ideally, the script shouldn't wait anything if called when there is not a selection. I don't know how `gedit` passes the input selection to the script and couldn't find a solution to just do nothing when there is no a selection.

Comment: I would assume that it passes the region as standard input. There is no simple way for a Bash script to determine that standard input is empty (it will always be when you start, and then you wait) but perhaps there could be a way on the `gedit` side to control this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Read-Timeout.html for how to implement a read timeout with GNU awk.

With input from stdin (enter 7 then Enter/Return then Control-D):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}'
7
#7
```

or with input from a pipe:

```
$ seq 2 | gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}'
#1
#2
```

or from a file:

```
$ seq 2 > file
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}' file
#1
#2
```

but if you don't provide any input and wait 5 seconds:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}'
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: error reading input file `-': Connection timed out
$
```

You can always redirect stderr the usual way if you don't want to see the timeout message:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}' 2>/dev/null
$
```

but of course that would mask ALL error messages so you might want to do this instead to just mask that one message:

```
{ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}' 2>&1 >&3 |
    grep -v 'fatal: error reading input file'; } 3>&1
```

e.g.:

```
$ { gawk 'BEGIN{print "other error" >"/dev/stderr";
        PROCINFO["-", "READ_TIMEOUT"]=5000} {print "#" $0}' 2>&1 >&3 |
    grep -v 'fatal: error reading input file'; } 3>&1
other error
$
```

Obviously change the `5000` to however many milliseconds you want the script to wait for input.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It looks like that, on macos, `gawk` is not defined, so I couldn't check your answer. Maybe my question was misleading, but I don't necessary need `awk` to have read timeout; I'm trying to find a way to prepend the `#` character to each line of a selection, when there is a selection, and do nothing otherwise.

Comment: You can install gawk on macos (I have). Understood on your needs, just showing you one way to, I think, get the functionality you want working. There may of course be other ways with other tools, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will install `gawk` and test your solution.